# How to join returned values from named range separated by comma

Tags: arrays, excel, vba, join, named-ranges

I've spent hours trying to find out how to join returned values from a named range, but the result is a

> run-time error 32 - Type mismatch.

As a newbie I'm still struggling with arrays, so maybe I've overlooked some detail. Thank you for helping me out.

Example: (B1)Benzine, (B2)Diesel, (B3)Hybride -> (E1)Gasoline, (E2)Diesel, (E3)Hybrid

This is the named range:
[image: Named Range: MOTOR]

**Another example (to be more clear):**

Example 2: (B1)Benzine, (B3)Hybride -> (E1)Gasoline, (E3)Hybrid

[image: Named Range: MOTOR]

```
Option Explicit

Sub splitter()

Dim i As Long
Dim w As Long
'Dim oWB As Workbook
Dim oWS As Worksheet
Dim oWS9 As Worksheet
Dim rngMOTOR As Range
Dim rngMOTOR2 As Range
Dim arrMOTOR() As Variant
Dim LastRow As Long

'Set oWB = Workbooks("BRONBESTAND.xlsm")
Set oWS = Sheets("ONDERDELEN")
Set oWS9 = Sheets("MOTOR")                                              '5 columns: 1 Short & LONG + 1 NL + 3 Languages !!!!! WARNING

LastRow = oWS.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

    For i = 2 To LastRow                                                                             'Starting below headers


        Set rngMOTOR = oWS.Cells(i, "M")                                                                'MOTOR      ...
        Set rngMOTOR2 = oWS9.Range("MOTOR")                                                 'MOTOR2: MOTOR - Bronbestand       arrPOS = rngPOS2.Value

        arrMOTOR = rngMOTOR2.Value


'*********
Dim txt As String
Dim j As Integer
Dim Splitted As Variant
Dim arrMOTORall As Variant
Dim arrMOTORsplit As Variant
Dim Motor3 As String

txt = oWS.Cells(i, "M")                                                                'MOTOR      ...

        Debug.Print ("txt : ") & i & ": "; txt

    If Not IsEmpty(txt) Then

        Splitted = Split(txt, ", ")
        For j = 0 To UBound(Splitted)

                Cells(1, j + 1).Value = Splitted(j)
                        Debug.Print ("                ---> Splitted: ") & Splitted(j)

        '**** INSERT *****


                For w = LBound(arrMOTOR) To UBound(arrMOTOR)
                    If arrMOTOR(w, 1) = Splitted(j) Then                                                                    'EX: B - Benzine
                            arrMOTORsplit = (arrMOTOR(w, 4))                                                               '(arrMOTOR(y, 2)) -> 1=SHORT+LONG , 2=NL, 3=FR, 4=EN
                                    Debug.Print ("                ---> arrMOTORsplit: ") & i & ": " & arrMOTORsplit

        '**** JOIN ****
                            arrMOTORall = Join(arrMOTORsplit, ", ")
                                    Debug.Print ("arrMOTORall: ") & arrMOTORall


                    End If
                Next w
        Next j
    End If

   Next i
End Sub
```

Comment: `arrMOTORsplit` contains a single value doesn't it, not an array?

Comment: arrMOTORsplit is the single returned value (the corresponding translation) that's on the same row as the value from the first split. I want to join these single values. Ex: Benzine, Hybride -> Gasoline, Hybrid

Comment: Found an innovative solution in **ANY order of combinations** - will edit my answer :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Get comma separated strings for each column in named range**

I didn't analyze your code, but this should work to receive the first three values joined

```
"Benzine, Diesel, Hybride"  ' e.g. from first column
```

or

```
"Gasoline, Diesel, Hybrid"  ' e.g. from the fourth column
```

from a named range "Motor" via the `Application.Index` function.

**Notes**

The parameter 0 in this `Index` function indicates to not choose a specific row, the Parameter `ColNo` chooses each of your columns in a Loop. A subsequent *transposition* allows to change the 2 dimensioned array values to a 1-dim array. The `Join` function needs a 1-dim array and concatenates the chosen column items therein.

*Hint:* The following sample code uses a fully qualified range reference assuming that you don't call the `TestMe` procedure from your *Personal Macro Library*. In the latter case you'd have to change references and workbook identification (not using **`ThisWorkbook`**!).

**Example code**

```
Option Explicit      ' declaration head of your code module

Sub TestMe()
Dim v As Variant, ColNo As Long
' assign first three rows to variant 1-based 2-dim datafield array
  v = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Motor").[Motor].Resize(3, 4) ' Named range value
' write comma separated list for each column
  For ColNo = 1 To 4
      Debug.Print Join(Application.Transpose(Application.Index(v, 0, ColNo)), ", ")
  Next ColNo
End Sub
```

> **EDIT - Flexible Search in ANY ORDER to translate joined lists**

This solution allows to return joined search words in *any combination* using the `Application.Index` function in an advanced way using row and column arrays as parameters. The main function `getSplitters()` creates a variant 2-dim array in only three steps **without loops and redims** and uses two language constants (Const DUTCH and Const ENGLISH).:

1. assigns data to variant 1-based 2-dim datafield array
2. gets only the selected rows based on comma separated string values
3. reduces the same array to Dutch and English columns

**Calling Code**

Due to your OP the calling code anylyzes all comma separated strings in Column `M` in your sheet `"ONDERDELEN"` as far as there are values in column A. This is made by passing these found string values to the main function `getSplitters` with an **innovative approach** to get results in *only three steps without Loops* (see function code below).

Translation is based on values in the named range `Motor` `"B1:E4"` in sheet `"Motor"` where rows comprise different sort of fuel with neighbouring columns for different languages (starting with Dutch in the first column and English in the fourth col).

*Note that using VBA it is faster to loop through an array to get values than through a range.*

```
Option Explicit             ' declaration head of your code module
Const DUTCH   As Integer = 1
Const ENGLISH As Integer = 4

Sub TranslateAnyFuelCombination()
' Purpose: returns comma separated lists in column "M" and translates from Dutch to English
' Example: "Benzine, Hybride, Diesel" (Dutch) gets to "Gasoline, Hybrid, Diesel" in English
  Dim s As String
  Dim oWS As Worksheet, i&, LastRow&, vMOTOR As Variant
  Set oWS = Thisworkbook.Worksheets("ONDERDELEN")   ' fully qualified reference
' Get last row of wanted data
  LastRow = oWS.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
  vMOTOR = oWS.Range("M1:M" & LastRow)
  For i = 2 To LastRow                       'Starting below headers
      Debug.Print getSplitters(vMOTOR(i, 1))
  Next i
End Sub
```

**Main function**

```
Function getSplitters(ByVal sRows As String) As String
  Dim i As Long, j    As Long
  Dim v As Variant, a As Variant
' [0] analyze selected rows string, e.g. "Benzine, Hybride, Diesel"
  a = getRowAr(sRows)          ' -> assign 1-dim Rows Array(1, 3, 2)
' [1] assign data to variant 1-based 2-dim datafield array
  v = Application.Transpose(ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Motor").[Motor])      ' Named range value
' [2] get only selected rows, e.g. 1st, 3rd and 2nd -> in free order (!) Benzine, Hybride, Diesel
  v = Application.Transpose(Application.Index(v, _
      Application.Evaluate("row(1:" & UBound(v, 2) & ")"), _
      a))                      ' transposed columns array = selected rows
' [3] reduce to Dutch and English columns
  v = Application.Transpose(Application.Index(v, _
      Application.Evaluate("row(1:" & (UBound(a) + 1) & ")"), _
      Array(DUTCH, ENGLISH)))               ' selected columns array (above array retransposed)
' [4] return concatenated strings
  getSplitters = Join(Application.Transpose(Application.Transpose(Application.Index(v, 1, 0))), ", ") & " -> " & _
                 Join(Application.Transpose(Application.Transpose(Application.Index(v, 2, 0))), ", ")
End Function
```

**Two helper functions**

```
Function getRowAr(ByVal sList As String) As Variant
' Purpose: split comma separated list into 1-dim number array in FREE ORDER
' Example: "Benzine, Hybride, Diesel" -> Array(1, 3, 2)
  Dim ar, i&
' change words in comma separated list to numbers
  ar = Split(Replace(sList, " ", ""), ",")
  For i = LBound(ar) To UBound(ar)
      ar(i) = val(getNumber(ar(i)))                ' change to numbers
  Next i
  getRowAr = ar                                    ' return
End Function

Function getNumber(ByVal s As String) As Long
' Purpose: replaces dutch search words with corresponding row number
  Dim arFuel
' get search words to 1-dim array
  arFuel = Application.Index(ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Motor").[Motor], 0, DUTCH)
' return corresponding number
  getNumber = Application.Match(s, arFuel)
End Function
```

> **Addendum** *(Edit due to comment)*

The above code works as intended if you are sure that the concatenated search words (or starting parts) *actually match* else an Error 13 is raised. You can solve this issue in two steps:

1. Insert an **empty first row** into your named range `Motor` (or fill it e.g. with `?`, `#N/A` etc.)
2. Change the 2nd helper function as follows:

**Edited function `getNumber()`**

```
 Function getNumber(ByVal s As String) As Long
 ' Purpose: replaces dutch search words with corresponding row number
   Dim arFuel
 ' get search words to 1-dim array
   arFuel = Application.Index(ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Motor").[Motor], 0, DUTCH)
 ' return corresponding number
   On Error Resume Next                             ' provide for not found case
   getNumber = Application.Match(s, arFuel, 0)      ' find only exact matches
   If Err.Number <> 0 Then getNumber = 0            ' could be omitted in case of a zero return
 End Function
```

Comment: Hi T.M., I've tried to integrate your code, but could only get a full column into the join. So I tried to get for 

Ex: Benzine, Hybride -> Gasoline, Hybrid or another combination, 

but couldn't get it to work yet. I got stuck on the comparing part:

If arrMOTOR(w, 1) = Splitted(j) Then

Comment: @W.Duri - Do you want to execute for example something like "Show me the concatenated 1st and 3rd row values in column 1 and add the corresponding concatenation in column 4 to get a result string." ?

Comment: Yes, so what happens is:
1) A user inputs any (concatenated) combination from a listbox in Dutch (column 1) 
2) I split into separate values 
3) And indeed, lookup the translated value (for example English: column 4). 
4) The last step (where I'm stuck) is to get translated values concatenated

Comment: I've just tried your code, but I'm getting a Run-time error '13': Type mismatch on part [2]  where a is getting implemented.

Comment: @W.Duri - edited my answer to reply to your comment; hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you very much. I've figured out that the Run-time error '13' is occuring when there's no value entered in the one of the rows in column M - ONDERDELEN. It would be great if an empty value could be replaced with a "-" instead. I thought about using isempty somehow, but I'm not sure where to put it. My best guess is around "ar" in Function getRowAr.

Comment: @W.Duri - Glad my approach is useful. As to your question: simply **insert a first row into your named range `Motor` and fill all values with "-" as I suggested in the addendum edit and check if the complete range is redefined.

Answer (score 1):

With 2 arrays this is a possible solution:

```
Sub TestMe()

    Dim inputString As String
    Dim arrString As Variant
    Dim arrResult As Variant

    inputString = "Benzine, Diesel, Hybride"
    arrString = Split(inputString, ",")

    Dim total As Long: total = UBound(arrString)
    ReDim arrResult(total)

    Dim i As Long
    For i = LBound(arrString) To UBound(arrString)
        arrResult(total - i) = Trim(arrString(i))
    Next i

    Debug.Print Join(arrResult, " ,")

End Sub
```

However, there is a classic solution of this problem, reversing everything twice:

```
Sub TestMe()

    Dim inputString As String
    inputString = "Benzine, Diesel, Hybride"
    inputString = StrReverse(inputString)
    Dim arr As Variant: arr = Split(inputString, ",")

    Dim i As Long
    For i = LBound(arr) To UBound(arr)
        arr(i) = Trim(StrReverse(arr(i)))
    Next i

    Debug.Print Join(arr, ", ")

End Sub
```

Comment: Hi Vitayata, Thank you for the quick reply. I've played around with your solution, but couldn't integrate the comparing part  to achieve for Ex: (B1)Benzine, (B3)Hybride -> (E1)Gasoline, (E3)Hybrid or another combination.

Comment: @Vityata, find your answers helpful in any case +1. - BTW I edited my answer to demonstrate an innovative and fully flexible approach which might be of some interest for you.  :-)