# Excel-VBA - Insert new first column in datafield array without loops or API calls

Tags: arrays, vba, excel, matrix

**Intro**

Last year @PrzemyslawRemin posed the question [how to add a counter column to an existing matrix in VBA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46712110/how-to-add-a-counter-column-to-existing-matrix-in-vba) **without additional loops** and **without modifying a worksheet**.

The original matrix in this example was a (1-based 2-dim) datafield array resulting from (source cells simply contain their address strings; the inserted row to be filled with numbers)

```
Dim matrix As Variant
matrix = Range("A1:C5").value
```

**Input matrix:    ------------                   ▼   Desired result:**

```
+----+----+----+   +----+----+----+----+ 
| A1 | B1 | C1 |   |  1 | A1 | B1 | C1 |
+----+----+----+   +----+----+----+----+ 
| A2 | B2 | C2 |   |  2 | A2 | B2 | C2 | 
+----+----+----+   +----+----+----+----+
| A3 | B3 | C3 |   |  3 | A3 | B3 | C3 | 
+----+----+----+   +----+----+----+----+ 
| A4 | B4 | C4 |   |  4 | A4 | B4 | C4 | 
+----+----+----+   +----+----+----+----+ 
| A5 | B5 | C5 |   |  5 | A5 | B5 | C5 | 
+----+----+----+   +----+----+----+----+
```

Of course the idea suggesting itself is to use a redimmed `newMatrix` as *Dy.Lee* proposed, but this would include two **loops** to shift rows and columns:

```
Sub test()
Dim matrix As Variant, newMatrix()
Dim i As Long, n As Long, c As Long, j As Long
matrix = Range("A1:C5").Value
n = UBound(matrix, 1)
c = UBound(matrix, 2)
ReDim newMatrix(1 To n, 1 To c + 1)
For i = 1 To n
    newMatrix(i, 1) = i
    For j = 2 To c + 1
        newMatrix(i, j) = matrix(i, j - 1)
    Next j
Next i
Range("a1").Resize(n, c + 1) = newMatrix
End Sub
```

Another **work around** avoiding unnecessary loops would be to write the array back to a temporary worksheet starting at column B and collect the data from there again including column A:D, but this means modifying a worksheet.

*Florent B.* alone [solved](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46712110/how-to-add-a-counter-column-to-existing-matrix-in-vba/46834384?s=1|55.9371#46834384) the problem via extremely fast **API calls** using `MemCopy` and there appeared no other approach since. - So for principal reasons it is of some interest if this should be the *ultima ratio* or if there can be found another approach.

**► Modified question (No duplicate!)**

Is there any possibility to insert a new first "column" in the existing datafield array

- without loops over "rows" and "columns" to shift the existing values,
- without worksheet modifications and
- without API calls using VBA?

Different from Prezmyslaw's OP I'm not using huge data sets, so that a limitation to approximately 64k rows would be possible (c.f. max. transposing limitation).

Answer (score 12, accepted):

**Found solution via the `Application.Index` function**

I found a solution simply by trying out some *unusual* variations of the **`Application.Index`** function which I try to resume as a comprehensive **generic** overview to demonstrate the rich range of application. So any helpful addition is welcome (c.f. @chrisneilsen 's comment).

**Some peculiarities of the the `Application.Index` function**

Typically the index function would deliver a well defined item by its row and column position, but there are some not so widely known pecularities:

0. Similarly to the `Worksheet.Index` function you can get the entire column or row items if the row or column number argument is set to zero (0). - *Another frequently unknown way to create a 2-dim array by passing a double-zero parameter can be found at [How to initialize a 2-dim array in Excel VBA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24584088/how-to-initialize-a-multidimensional-array-variable-in-vba-for-excel/66969472#66969472)*
1. **Use of array arguments possible** - This function allows not only the known index indications by given numbers, but also **array parameters** to extract "rows" or "columns", so it's possible to indicate a wanted set of columns, e.g.`A:C` via `Array(1,2,3)` as column array argument.
2. **Filtering effects** - Furthermore I learnt that it is possible to reduce the choice to some columns (rows) only, e.g. via `Array(1,3) and even to change the internal order, e.g.` Array(3,2,1)`.
3. **Restructuring** - The most surprising fact, however, is that it is possible to **repeat** a column choice, e.g. via `Array(1,1,2,3)`
   or even `Array(0,1,2,3)` where the `0` item is the same as column 1. This can be used to reach the same effect as a column  insertion.

This *last restructuring capability* of the mentioned `Index` function is the key part of my approach:

**Code example**

```
Sub AddFirstIndexColumn()
  Dim v, i&, ws As Worksheet
  Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("SourceSheet")  ' << change to source sheet name
' [1] get data
      v = ws.[A1:C5].Value2
' [2] define column array inserting first column (0 or 1) and preserving old values (1,2,3)
      v = Application.Index(v, _
          Application.Evaluate("row(1:" & UBound(v) & ")"), _
          Array(0, 1, 2, 3))   ' columns array where 0 reinserts the first column
' [3] add an current number in the first column
      For i = LBound(v) To UBound(v): v(i, 1) = i: Next i
 End Sub
```

**How to test the result**

Just insert the following to the code above:

```
' [4a] test result by debugging in immediate window
      For i = LBound(v) To UBound(v)
          Debug.Print "#" & i & ": " & Join(Application.Index(v, i, 0), ", ")
      Next i
' [4b] test result by writing back to target sheet
      Dim ws2 As Worksheet
      Set ws2 = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("TargetSheet")  ' << change to target sheet name
      ws2.Range("A1").Resize(UBound(v), UBound(v, 2)).Offset(0, 0) = v
```

**Caveat**

The found solution seems to be restricted to 65536 rows (possibly similar to array transposing limitation), so that you can't use it for bigger data.

**Some recent `Application.Index` examples**

- [Copy from sheet1 columns A,B,C,G,F,R,S,T to sheet2 in columns A,B,C,D,E,F,G,H](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51602689/copy-from-sheet1-cols-a-b-c-g-f-r-s-t-to-sheet-2-in-colums-a-b-c-d-e-f-g-h/51608764#51608764)
- [Multi criteria selection with VBA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51519145/multi-criteria-selection-with-vba/51524230#51524230)
- [How to join returned values from named range separated by comma](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51282481/how-to-join-returned-values-from-named-range-separated-by-comma/51293412#51293412)

Comment: FYI while the approach of using `INDEX` is interesting, for _this_ application it is significantly slower than either the Loops approach, or the API approach.  Looping runs in approx half the time, and the API in half that again (tested on a range of 10,000 rows). FWIW, I know you framed the Q as "without additional loops ...", but IMHO that's an arbitary constraint that offers no value.  Ruling out API calls would be valid if the code was required to run on a mac.

Comment: Appreciate your valuable feed back. I totally agree with you that *loops* are unbeatable when *timing* for greater data sets is paramount. - 
My intention *here* was to enrich the set of conventional solutions out of curiosity and for the sake of the art. While diving into the *pecularities* of `INDEX` just by experimenting, I discovered a real treasure of restructuring possibilities which I tried to list as helpful **generic** overview. Therefore *any* helpful addition like yours is welcome. @chrisneilsen

Comment: *As to the API approach:* I deliberately excluded the API call I specifically mentioned in the original post because, in my opinion, it has already been answered with certain restrictions. - However, I am considering to ask a new, extended question focussing on the API issue :-) @chrisneilsen