# Find Existing String in 2-D Array

Tags: vba, excel

I'm collecting data from a spreadsheet and storing it in a 2-D Array, the idea is that once the script detects it's reading from a specific column, it would not read an entire row of the data (as this would be considered a duplicate).

**CODE:**

```
Private Sub LoadData()

   cDOC_DEBUG "Loading document data..."
   Dim x As Long  'Column Data - there is another function that reads when x = 0 = header; else every other value is considered "data"
   Dim y As Long 

   With dataWS
      For x = 1 To LR - 1
         For y = 1 To LC - 1
            If (IsInArray(.Cells(x + 1, y + 1).value, pData())) Then
               cDOC_DEBUG "Added: " & .Cells(x + 1, y + 1).value
               pData(x, y) = Trim(.Cells(x + 1, y + 1).value)
            End If
         Next y
      Next x
   End With

End Sub

Private Function IsInArray(stringToBeFound As String, arrString As Variant) As Boolean
   IsInArray = (UBound(Filter(arrString, stringToBeFound)) > -1)
End Function

Private Sub cDOC_DEBUG(debugText As String)
   If (ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Settings").Cells(3, 2)) Then
      Debug.Print debugText
   End If
End Sub
```

Everything is loading into the array fine, until I start implementing my `IsInArray` function. I can see it has to do with the fact that it's searching through a single dimensional array, and my array is two dimensional; so it makes sense that it's getting a type mismatch error.

Each row within the spreadsheet is a segment of information that correlates to it's self.

**Initial Data From Spreadsheet:**

```
        A           B           C           D
1    header1     header2     header3     header4
2       a           b           c           d
3       w           x           y           z
4       a           h           j           j
5       a           b           j           d
6       w           x           u           z
```

**2x2 Final Array:**

```
        0           1           2           3
0    header1     header2     header3     header4
1       a           b           c           d
2       w           x           y           z
3       a           h           j           j
```

Because Header1 & Header2 & Header4 from Excel rows 5 & 6 have the same values as Excel rows 2 and 3, this will not be read into the array.

**Question:**

How would I match the criteria above to not include the duplicates from a row.

> **Example Sudo Code:**
>
> If (Value being added matches all values from column Header1 & Header2 & Header3_ Then
>
> Don't add to array

Another issue that I am aware of, is that there will be blank data within this array; is there something I can do to either 1 remove these or will I have to have another index for the array slots to keep track of?

Comment: To clarify, that's called a 2-D (or 2 dimensional) array.  (I think 2x2 would imply there are a total of 4 elements ie., `A1:B2`).  Beyond that - maybe I don't fully understand your definition of "duplicate" here -- you want to remove rows where "header 3" is duplicated?

Comment: @ashleedawg Sorry, yes you are correct it is a 2-D array. To clarify, if there is a duplicate value found in Header1 and Header2 and Header3 this item would not be added to the array. In the example you can see that rows 5&6 were classified as duplicates and thus not included in the array. Array Row 5 was equal to Excel Row 2 and Array Row 6 was equal to Excel Row 3.

Comment: I think there's a much easier way than using VBA but I'm still not clear. If Header 1 **or** Header 2 **or** Header 3 have duplicates?

Comment: ...I don't understand because there's still a duplicate in the first column.

Comment: @ashleedawg Right, that is fine, so the criteria needs to be (Header1 & Header2 & Header3), you're thinking it in terms (Header1 Or Header2 Or Header3). I apologize about my explanation; I am having a hard time wording that lol

Comment: ...Do you mean "matches **any**" instead of "all".  It can't match "all" unless all 4 columns are the same

Comment: In your example "final array", the first column still has duplicates (`a`'s) and the last row still has duplicates (`j`'s)... I don't understand

Comment: @ashleedawg I am not comparing individual values from a single row, I'm comparing rows against each other. Row 5 was equal to Row 2, so it was not included in the final array. Row 6 was equal to Row 3, so it was not included in the final array. ONLY using columns A, B, and D; Column C was not including in the criteria

Comment: @Maldred, added a solution using a dictionary check and `Application.Index` function. would appreciate your feed back :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can loop rows/columns and use `Index` to slice a row/column out of the array and use `Match` to test if search value is in that column. Combine with `Count` to test for duplicates. If the count equals the number of columns ignore value (or column count  -1... see next comment ==>). Not entirely sure about this imaginary column. Do you intend to dimension at start with an additional empty column?

**Row Versions:**

Exists:

```
Option Explicit
Public Sub CheckRow()
    Dim arr(), i As Long
    arr = [A1:D6].Value                          '<==2D array created

    For i = LBound(arr, 1) To UBound(arr, 1)     '<== loop rows
        'look in each row for x and if found exit loop and indicate row where found
        If Not IsError(Application.Match("x", Application.WorksheetFunction.Index(arr, i, 0), 0)) Then
            Debug.Print "value found in column " & i
            Exit For
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

Duplicates:

```
Option Explicit
Public Sub CheckRow()
    Dim arr(), i As Long
    arr = [A1:D6].Value                          '<==2D array created

    For i = LBound(arr, 1) To UBound(arr, 1)     '<== loop rows
        'look in each row for more than one "B" and if found exit loop and indicate row where found
         If Application.Count(Application.Match(Application.WorksheetFunction.Index(arr, i, 0), "B", 0)) > 1 Then
            Debug.Print i
            Exit For
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

exists:

---

**Columns versions:**

Exists:

```
Option Explicit
Public Sub CheckColumn()
    Dim arr(), i As Long
    arr = [A1:D6].Value                          '<==2D array created

    For i = LBound(arr, 2) To UBound(arr, 2)     '<== loop columns
        'look in each column for x and if found exit loop and indicate column where found
        If Not IsError(Application.Match("x", Application.WorksheetFunction.Transpose(Application.WorksheetFunction.Index(arr, 0, i)), 0)) Then
            Debug.Print "value found in column " & i
            Exit For
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

Duplicates:

You can use `Count` to check for duplicates within an entire column, again sliced with `Index`:

```
Option Explicit
Public Sub CheckColumn()
    Dim arr(), i As Long
    arr = [A1:D6].Value                          '<==2D array created

    For i = LBound(arr, 2) To UBound(arr, 2)     '<== loop columns
        'look in each column for more than one "B" and if found exit loop and indicate column where found
         If Application.Count(Application.Match(Application.WorksheetFunction.Transpose(Application.WorksheetFunction.Index(arr, 0, i)), "B", 0)) > 1 Then
            Debug.Print i
            Exit For
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

---

Using sample data in sheet:

[image: data]

Comment: I want to find the row and slice the row out, not columns... I'm not sure if this would qualify for what I'm looking for.

Comment: Your wording was "How would I search an entire (theoretical) column "  - so definitely rows? I can easily change to rows.

Comment: @QHarr - Woluldn't "remove duplicates" be much easier?  I'm not clear on the details - you might have to run it 3 times each time with one column selected.. or maybe i totally misunderstand?

Comment: My apologies, I have edited the question to be more specific to what I am looking for

Comment: You can use Count version,. I think, and if count = 4 or whatever the magic number is then don't add.

Comment: @ashleedawg I no longer know. If OP can use the above great. Otherwise, I can delete and go grab a .

Comment: @QHarr I will try the Count version and see what I can get, that seems to be the best solution. I will get back to you once I get it working. Thanks for the help!

Comment: @Maldred - referring to the above comment: did you try the proposed approaches and get them working? So you could help other readers  to identify helpful solutions by accepting and/or upvoting :-)

Answer (score 0):

**Alternative using advanced `Index` function**

This approach using a (late bound) dictionary  should be helpful, if your data rows don't exceed the number of *65536*. You'll get a 2-dim (1-based) array `v` with the unique data set of columns A,B and D.

In this example code results are written back to e.g. columns F:H and values of column C are omitted; if you want to maintain these values see ► **Edit** below.

**Example code (omitting column C in resulting array)**

```
Sub getUniqueRows()
Dim dict As Object, v, i&, ii&, n&, currRow$
Set dict = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")         ' late binding dictionary
With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("MySheet")                 ' << change to your sheet name
  n = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row - 1     ' n items (omitting header line)
' [1] get data
  v = .Range("A2:D" & n + 1).Value
' [2a]remove column C (i.e. allow columns 1, 2 and 4 only)
  v = Application.Index(v, Evaluate("row(1:" & n & ")"), Array(1, 2, 4))
' [2b] check for unique ones
  For i = 1 To n
     currRow = Join(Application.Index(v, i, 0), ",") ' build string of cells A,B & D
     If Not dict.Exists(currRow) Then dict.Add currRow, i
  Next i
' [3] remove duplicate rows
  v = Application.Transpose(Application.Index(v, dict.Items, Evaluate("row(1:" & 3 & ")")))
' [4] write data to any wanted range
  .Range("F:H") = ""                                 ' clear rows
  .Range("F2").Resize(UBound(v), 3) = v              ' write data
End With
Set dict = Nothing
End Sub
```

**Note**

The `dict.Items` collection in section [3] is an array of all found item numbers in the dictionary and allows the `Index` function to get only these items.

**Additional links**

See [Insert new first column in datafield array without loops or API call](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51688593/excel-vba-insert-new-first-column-in-datafield-array-without-loops-or-api-call/51714153#51714153)

**Edit - maintain values in column C**

> *Due to comment:* "ONLY using columns A, B, and D; Column C was not including in the criteria."

If you want to check values only in A,B and D, but maintain the *C values* in the resulting array you can use the following *optimized* code neglecting an empty values row.

```
Sub getUniqueRows2()
Dim dict As Object, v, i&, n&, j&, currRow$
Set dict = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")          ' late binding dictionary
With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("MySheet")                  ' << change to your sheet name
     n = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row - 1      ' items counter  (omitting header line)
   ' [1] get data
     v = .Range("A2:D" & n + 1).Value
   ' [2] check for unique ones
     For i = 1 To UBound(v)
       ' assign ONLY criteria of 1st, 2nd & 4th column to string value currRow
         currRow = ""
         For j = 0 To 2: currRow = currRow & v(i, Array(1, 2, 4)(j)) & ",": Next j
       ' add first unique occurrence to dictionary
         If Not dict.Exists(currRow) Then                 ' add first occurrence
             If Len(currRow) > 3 Then dict.Add currRow, i ' ... and ignore empty values
         End If
     Next i
   ' [3] remove duplicate rows
     v = Application.Transpose(Application.Index(v, dict.Items, Evaluate("row(1:" & 4 & ")")))
   ' [4] write resulting array values anywhere, e.g. to columns F:I
     .Range("F:I") = ""                                   ' clear rows
     .Range("F2").Resize(UBound(v), 4) = v                ' write data
End With
Set dict = Nothing
End Sub
```