# Joining two arrays in vba?

Tags: arrays, excel, vba

How do I combine these arrays with the outcome of `(2, 4, 5, 3, 7, 6)`?

```
array1 = Array(4,5,3,7,6)

array2 = Array(2)
```

Comment: Create a third array that is empty the size of both arrays combined, then loop through each array adding the items one by one.

Comment: FYI added an alternative to @ScottCraner 's comment how to combine two 1-dim arrays using the advanced possibilities of the `Application.Index()` function :-)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You could potentially `Join()` and concatenate your two arrays, and then `Split()` the result back to a new array:

```
array3 = Split(Join(array2, ",") & "," & Join(array1, ","), ",")
```

**Explanation:**
`Join()` will return a string that has each element in the array (first parameter) delimited by a `","` (second parameter). We concatenate those two joined arrays with one more comma to get a string like `2,4,5,3,7,6`. We then use `Split()` to turn that string back into an array telling `Split()` that the delimter is a comma `","`.

Comment: One caveat is that the return will be a string, and as such may need to have some other work done to it when retrieving the values.

Comment: The return of `Split()` will be an array, but yes... the return of the `JOIN()` will be a string and if an element contains the delimiter being used, then the array returned by `Split()` will be spaghetti.

Comment: The return of `Split` will be an array of strings.

Comment: Ah! @ScottCraner That's a good caveat! It is totally hacky, but you know I love a good hacky one-liner.

Comment: FYI `"You know I love a good hacky one-liner."` - Added another solution to "joining two array" using `Application.Index()` as a one-liner and maintaining the original types of array values (As `Index()` results in 1-based results, I need a further ReDimming back to a zero-based array to maintain the orginal settings).

Answer (score 4):

You could use arrayLists. This also provides for an easy sort if wanted.

```
Option Explicit
Public Sub test()
    Dim list1 As Object, list2 As Object

    Set list1 = CreateObject("System.Collections.Arraylist")
    Set list2 = CreateObject("System.Collections.Arraylist")
    list1.Add 4
    list1.Add 5
    list1.Add 3
    list1.Add 7
    list1.Add 6
    list2.Add 2
    list1.addRange list2
    list1.Sort
End Sub
```

Comment: FYI Added an alternative  to "joining two arrays" via arrayLists. :+)

Comment: Out of interest: is there a function comparable to `Join()` that can be applied on arrayLists, as e.g. `Debug.Print Join(list1, "|")` object would result in an Error 13 Type mismatch.

Comment: @T.M. Yes you can > `Join(list1.ToArray,"|")` =)

Answer (score 3):

**Joining two arrays**

As an alternative to the correct and working approach proposed by Scott Craner

> *Create a third array that is empty the size of both arrays combined, 
>   then loop through each array adding the items one by one.*

... I demonstrate a way to

- insert *only* the element(s) of the **2nd array** by a *loop* 
  into a main array, whereas
- the **main array** gets only *restructured* by a *one liner* via `Application.Index()`.

As this function would change results to a 1-based array, I redimension the array back to a zero-based one. Furthermore I added an optional display in the VBE's Immediate Window resulting to `2|4|5|3|7|6` values:

**1st step: Simple demo with same array values as in OP (Insertion of 1 element)**

```
Sub SimpleDemo()
'[0]declare and assign zero-based 1-dimensioned arrays
    Dim main, newTop
    main = Array(4, 5, 3, 7, 6)
    newTop = Array(2)              ' only one element in a first step
'[1]transform main array by inserting(/i.e. repeating) "another" 1st element
    main = Application.Index(main, Array(1, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5)) ' changes to 1-based 1-dim array
    ReDim Preserve main(0 To UBound(main) - 1)              ' back to zero-based 1-dim array
'[2]overwrite new first element by the 1st(only) element of newTop
    main(0) = newTop(0)
'[3](optional) display in VBE's Immediate Window: main(0 To 5) ~> 2|4|5|3|7|6
    Debug.Print "main(" & LBound(main) & " To " & UBound(main) & ") ~> " & _
                Join(main, "|")
End Sub
```

**2nd step: More generalized approach using a `AddElem` procedure**

The above demo inserts only *one* element. Therefore I coded a `AddElem` procedure and a help function `addedElems()` to allow the **insertion of more elements**. Assumption is made that all 1-dim arrays are zero-based as in the original post; could be adapted easily btw :-)

```
Sub AddElem(main, newTop)
' Purp. : add/insert other array element(s) on top of zero-based main array
' Author: https://stackoverflow.com/users/6460297/t-m
' Date  : 2020-02-05
' ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
' a)insert newTop element(s) on top of main array
    main = Application.Index(main, addedElems(main, newTop)) ' changes temporarily to 1-based mainay!
' b)make main array zero-based again (optional)
    ReDim Preserve main(0 To UBound(main) - 1)
' c)overwrite inserted starting element(s) by the newTop element(s)
    Dim i&: For i = 0 To UBound(newTop): main(i) = newTop(i): Next i
End Sub
```

**Help function `addedElems()`**

```
Function addedElems(main, newTop) As Variant()
'Note : help function called by AddElem()
'Purp.: return ordinal element counters of combined arrays
    Dim i&, n&: n = UBound(main) + UBound(newTop) + 1
    ReDim tmp(0 To n)
    For i = 0 To UBound(newTop): tmp(i) = i: Next i
    For i = i To n: tmp(i) = i - UBound(newTop): Next i
    addedElems = tmp        ' return combined elem counters,  e.g. Array(1,2, 1,2,3,4,5)
End Function
```

**Example call**

I changed the values of OP's second array slightly (`Array(2)` ~>`Array(20,21)` to demonstrate the insertion of more elements, thus 
resulting in a combined `Array(20,21,2,4,5,3,7,6)`.

```
Sub ExampleCall()
'[0]declare and assign zero-based 1-dimensional arrays
    Dim main, newTop
    main = Array(4, 5, 3, 7, 6)
    newTop = Array(20, 21)
'[1]Add/Insert newTop on top of main array
    AddElem main:=main, newTop:=newTop     ' or simply: AddElem main, newTop

'[2](optional) display in VBE's Immediate Window: ~~> main(0 To 6) ...20|21|4|5|3|7|6
    Debug.Print "main(" & LBound(main) & " To " & UBound(main) & ") ..." & _
                Join(main, "|")
End Sub
```

**Related link**

Similarly you can study some pecularities of the `Application.Index()` function applied on 2-dim arrays at [Insert first column in datafield array without loops or API calls](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51688593/excel-vba-insert-new-first-column-in-datafield-array-without-loops-or-api-call/51714153#51714153)

Comment: Upvoted for thorough explaination, Btw, seen you interested in `Application.Methods` lately =)

Answer (score 2):

Late to the party, but I'll also add my two cents

You could simply ***copy*** one of the two arrays into a new array. Then `Redim Preserve` that to be the size of the two original arrays to then loop ***only*** the first array. The following code is basic, but does the job quick without converting any data type:

```
Sub Test()

Dim arr1 As Variant: arr1 = Array(4, 5, 3, 7, 6)
Dim arr2 As Variant: arr2 = Array(2)
Dim arr3 As Variant: arr3 = arr2

ReDim Preserve arr3(UBound(arr1) + Ubound(arr2) + 1)
For x = (UBound(arr3) - UBound(arr1)) To UBound(arr3)
    arr3(x) = arr1(x - UBound(arr2) - 1)
Next x

End Sub
```

---

To demonstrate the return of different `Data Type` using some `Type` conversions:

```
Sub Test()

Dim arr1 As Variant: arr1 = Array(CDbl(4), CLng(5), CStr(3), CDate(7), CCur(6))
Dim arr2 As Variant: arr2 = Array(2)
Dim arr3 As Variant: arr3 = arr2

ReDim Preserve arr3(UBound(arr1) + Ubound(arr2) + 1)
For x = (UBound(arr3) - UBound(arr1)) To UBound(arr3)
    arr3(x) = arr1(x - UBound(arr2) - 1)
Next x

End Sub
```

[image]

Comment: Helpful and another fine approach demonstrating the same idea, not to loop through *each* array adding the items one by one :+)