# Copy data from rows in different column order

Tags: excel, vba, copying

I need to copy rows of data from one worksheet to another. But i have to change the order of the columns. For example Data from `A,B,C` in columns `E,L,J` and so on. I already worked on a solution and the code below hopefully shows what i want to do.

Is there a cleaner way to copy the data? My version is quite slow while executing.
How can i copy the data in the `target worksheet` without empty rows?

```
Sub KopieZeilenUmkehren()
    Dim Zeile As Long
    Dim ZeileMax As Long
    Dim n As Long

    With Sheets("Artikel")
        ZeileMax = .UsedRange.Rows.Count
        n = 1

        For Zeile = 2 To ZeileMax

            If .Cells(Zeile, 1).Value = "Ja" Then

                .Range("A" & Zeile).Copy Destination:=Worksheets("ArtikelNeu").Range("E" & Zeile)
                .Range("B" & Zeile).Copy Destination:=Worksheets("ArtikelNeu").Range("L" & Zeile)
                .Range("C" & Zeile).Copy Destination:=Worksheets("ArtikelNeu").Range("J" & Zeile)
                .Range("D" & Zeile).Copy Destination:=Worksheets("ArtikelNeu").Range("I" & Zeile)
                .Range("E" & Zeile).Copy Destination:=Worksheets("ArtikelNeu").Range("H" & Zeile)
                .Range("F" & Zeile).Copy Destination:=Worksheets("ArtikelNeu").Range("G" & Zeile)
                .Range("G" & Zeile).Copy Destination:=Worksheets("ArtikelNeu").Range("F" & Zeile)
                .Range("H" & Zeile).Copy Destination:=Worksheets("ArtikelNeu").Range("A" & Zeile)
                .Range("I" & Zeile).Copy Destination:=Worksheets("ArtikelNeu").Range("D" & Zeile)
                .Range("J" & Zeile).Copy Destination:=Worksheets("ArtikelNeu").Range("C" & Zeile)
                .Range("K" & Zeile).Copy Destination:=Worksheets("ArtikelNeu").Range("B" & Zeile)
                .Range("L" & Zeile).Copy Destination:=Worksheets("ArtikelNeu").Range("K" & Zeile)

                n = n + 1

            End If
        Next Zeile
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: What do you mean by Without Empty Rows ? this code will override whatever is there in the destination cell.

Comment: Posted a solution to your issue using the advanced possibilities of the `Application.Index` function and explained why you get all rows including empty ones. - Allow me a remark to you as new contributor: feel free to accept my post by marking the green check mark if you found it helpful.

Answer (score 0):

**Change column order and filter rows**

> *My version is quite slow while executing.*

Looping through a whole range by means of VBA is time consuming, you speed up the process assigning range data to a variant array `v` - c.f. section **`[1]`**.

```
    v = rng
```

Using the advanced possibilities of the `Application.Index` function it's possible to reorganize the entire array structure including row filtering for cell values (e.g. `"Ja"`) - c.f. section **`[2]`**.

```
    v = Application.Index(v, getRowNums(v, "Ja"), getColNums())
```

... and write it to any given target (c.f. section **`[3]`**) by only one code line.

```
    ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("ArtikelNeu").Range("A1").Resize(UBound(v), UBound(v, 2)) = v
```

**Example call**

```
Sub Restructure()
' Purpose: restructure range columns
  With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Artikel")                                              ' worksheet referenced e.g. via CodeName

    ' [0] identify range
      Dim rng As Range, lastRow&, lastCol&
      lastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row            ' get last row and last column
      lastCol = .Cells(1, .Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
      Set rng = .Range(.Cells(1, 1), .Cells(lastRow, lastCol))  ' define data range
    ' ~~~~~~~~~~~~
    ' [1] get data
    ' ~~~~~~~~~~~~
      Dim v: v = rng                                            ' assign to 1-based 2-dim datafield array
      Debug.Print rng.Address, "v(" & UBound(v) & "," & UBound(v, 2) & ")"

    ' ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    ' [2] restructure column order in array in a one liner
    ' ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
      v = Application.Index(v, getRowNums(v, "Ja"), getColNums())

  End With
' [3] write restructured data to target sheet
      With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("ArtikelNeu")
          .Cells.Clear
          .Range("A1").Resize(UBound(v), UBound(v, 2)) = v      ' write new data
      End With

End Sub
```

**Needed helper functions**

These two functions simply return an array of found row numbers as well as an array of the new column numbers.

```
Private Function getRowNums(data, ByVal search As String) As Variant()
' Purpose: return array of row numbers (including title row)
'          where cell in column A equals search criteria "Ja"
  Dim i&, ii&                     ' row counters
  ReDim tmp(1 To UBound(data))    ' temporary array
  ii = 1: tmp(ii) = 1             ' get title row (no 1) in any case
  For i = 2 To UBound(data)       ' check each row in first column (A)
      If LCase(data(i, 1)) = LCase(search) Then ii = ii + 1: tmp(ii) = i
  Next i
  ReDim Preserve tmp(1 To ii)     ' reduce total items to title row + findings
  Debug.Print "getRowNums = Array(" & Join(tmp, ",") & ")"      ' e.g. Array(1,2,4, ...)
  getRowNums = Application.Transpose(tmp)
End Function

Private Function getColNums() As Variant()
' Purpose: return array of new column number order, e.g. Array(5,12,10,9,8,7,6,1,4,3,2,11) based on columns E, L, J etc.
  Const NEWORDER = "E,L,J,I,H,G,F,A,D,C,B,K"  ' << change to wanted column order
  Dim i&, items: items = Split(NEWORDER, ",")
  ReDim tmp(1 To UBound(items) + 1)
' fill 1-based temporary array with col numbers (retrieved from letters A,B,C...
  For i = 0 To UBound(items)
      tmp(i + 1) = Range(items(i) & ":" & items(i)).Column
  Next i
    Debug.Print "getColNums = Array(" & Join(tmp, ",") & ")"    ' e.g. 5|12|10|9|8|7|6|1|4|3|2|11
  getColNums = tmp           ' return array with new column numbers (1-based)
End Function
```

**Hint to OP**

> *How can I copy the data in the target worksheet without empty rows?*

Changing code in original post using counter `n` allows to ignore empty rows. Instead of e.g. `.Range("A" & Zeile).Copy Destination:=Worksheets("ArtikelNeu").Range("E" & Zeile)` it should be

```
    .Range("A" & Zeile).Copy Destination:=Worksheets("ArtikelNeu").Range("E" & n)
```

In the example call above the filtering is executed by function `getRowNums(v,"Ja")`.

**Recommended link**

You find some pecularities of the `Application.Index` function at [Insert first column in datafield array without loops or API calls](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51688593/excel-vba-insert-new-first-column-in-datafield-array-without-loops-or-api-call/51714153#51714153)