# Set up variable to refer to sheet

Tags: excel, vba

Can I set up a variable x = "Sheet1"
In order to do:
x.Range("A3")
instead of 
Sheet1.Range("A3")?

What type of variable should it be? I tried string and it didn't work.

Thanks

Update:
I would like a method that won't be affected by changing the worksheet name. i.e.
Sheet1.Range("A3") will always refer to the same worksheet even if I change the worksheet name to "peanuts", at least that's what I thought.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You want to declare it a Worksheet Object:

```
Dim x as WorkSheet
```

Since it is an object we must `Set` the sheet:

```
Set x = WorkSheets("Sheet1")
```

or if you want to use the code name:

```
Set x = Sheet1
```

Then yes you can use it:

```
x.Range("A3")...
```

Comment: Thank you, is this referencing it by Name or by Code Name? Ideally I want an option that will not be affected by changing the worksheet name, which is what I thought
Sheet1.Range... ensured

Comment: @Agustin note that using a `Worksheet` variable for a worksheet object that exists in `ThisWorkbook` at compile-time, is 100% redundant, and very likely makes your code more confusing than it needs to be. A much better approach would be to give `Sheet1` a proper code name (that's the `(Name)` property), otherwise `x` is just a surrogate for `Sheet1`, and both are equally usable and valid. Don't declare variables that you don't need - and do declare the variables that you do need - e.g. anything you pull out of `Worksheets` is just `Object`: you *want* to pull that into a properly declared var.

Answer (score 1):

I think you're mixing two different declarations

Declaring a sheet (must `set` the sheet)

```
dim ws as worksheet
set ws = sheets("sheet1")
ws.cells(1,1).value = ""
```

Declaring a string as the name of a sheet (can utilize the NAME of the sheet as a string)

```
dim ws_name as string
ws_name = "sheet1"
sheets(ws_name).cells(1,1).value = ""
```

---

Additionally you could use the sheet index, which does not utilize the name of the sheet (if you change it later); this is a little different than the previous two, but this example (using a loop) helps more clearly explain how the index can be utilized

```
dim i as long
for i = 1 to sheets.count step 1
    sheets(i).cells(1,1).value = ""
next i
```

and a simple use of a sheet index

```
sheets(1).cells(1,1).value = ""
```

Answer (score 0):

It should be worksheet. The syntax would be:

```
Dim x as Worksheet
Set x = Sheet1
```

after that you can use `x.range("A3")` to refer to Cell A3 in sheet1

Answer (score 0):

You want a `Worksheet` variable. The "name" you're referring to is the `Name` property, and that isn't in code; it's the "tab name" of the sheet, *that the user can change on a whim* and that, for that reason, you don't want to have to hard-code anywhere if you can avoid it.

But it looks like you're referring to a sheet that exists in `ThisWorkbook` at compile-time; each sheet has a `(Name)` property that you can edit in the *Properties* toolwindow (<kbd>F4</kbd>). By default that name is `Sheet1`, and VBA takes that name and makes it a project-scope identifier you can use anywhere you need to refer to *that particular sheet*.

So if you change a sheet's `(Name)` to `PeanutsSheet`, then you can use `PeanutsSheet` in your code:

```
PeanutsSheet.Range("A1").Value = 42 '<~ that's the "CodeName", and users can't easily break it
```

And that is preferable to referring to that same sheet by its "tab name":

```
ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Peanuts").Range("A1").Value = 42 '<~ breaks if tab is ever renamed
```

Declaring a variable for a sheet that exists in `ThisWorkbook` at compile-time, is completely redundant:

```
Dim ws As Worksheet
Set ws = Sheet1 '<~ variable 'ws' is 100% redundant
```

Using such variables makes the code confusing and harder to follow than it needs to be, because now you have 2 (or more) identifiers referring to the same thing.

But this is worse:

```
Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1") '<~ now it's redundant *and* super frail
```