# Excel how to transform a table to be used for pivot: use the column headers in a field

Tags: excel, vba, data-modeling, excel-tables

I have a table in Excel that is filled as below

```
PROD         JAN-19     FEB-19    ...     ...

product1      123        098      ...     ...
product2      314        467      ...     ...
```

I would need to use the data in a pivot table so I suppose I should transform the datamodel in the following way using the MMM-YY header as data in the Year and Month field.

```
 PROD          Year    Month     Data

 Product1       19      JAN       123
 Product1       19      FEB       098
 ...           ...      ...       ...
```

Below a screen of the actual table and what I would like to achieve:
[image: screen]

Is there a practical way to do so either working on the Datamodel in which the table is uploaded or as last option VBA?.

Answer (score 0):

**Array Transformation via `Application.Index()`**

This approach assigns the table values to an array first and eventually transforms the same array to the wanted structure using the extended features of the `Application.Index()` function thus maintaining the product names.

I don't pretend this to be the most efficient way, but it clearly demonstrates the possibilities of the cited function - c.f. [Some pecularaties of the Application.Index function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51688593/excel-vba-insert-new-first-column-in-datafield-array-without-loops-or-api-call/51714153#51714153)

Further note: I assume that all month data are included, i.e. even empty values.

```
Sub Table2PivotBase()
' Purpose: Transform Table to Pivot base
' Method:  reorganize Datafield array of table using advanced features of Application.Index in [2]d)
' Note:    sheet references use the worksheet's CodeName property here
'~~~~~~~~~~~~ [0] Reference to table (address) ~~~~~~
Const MONTHSCOUNT& = 12, COLUMNOFFSET& = 1    ' number of months, column offset January = 1 (i.e. 2nd col)
With Sheet1
'a) Refer to table using the sheet's CodeName
    Dim rpt As ListObject
    Set rpt = .ListObjects("Table1")
Sheet1.CodeName
' ~~~~~~~~~~~ [1] Get Data ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
'b) Assign table values in Sheet1 to 2-dim 1-based array
    Dim arr As Variant, yr&
    arr = .Range(rpt.Range.Address).Value2
'c) Extract current year from 1st month column in header (1+ coloffset 1 => 2nd column)
    yr = Val(Split(arr(1, 1 + COLUMNOFFSET) & "-", "-")(1))
End With

'~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ [2] Reorganize Data ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
'd) Redimension array preserving 1st column
    Dim arr2, ItemsCount&
    ItemsCount = UBound(arr) - IIf(rpt.ShowTotals, 1, 0)    ' exclude table totals from items count
    arr2 = Application.Index(arr, Application.Transpose(getRowsArr(ItemsCount, MONTHSCOUNT)), Array(1, 1, 1, 2))

'e) Redefine headers in 1st row
    Dim no&, headers
    headers = Array("Product", "Year", "Month", "Data")
    For no = 1 To 4
        arr2(1, no) = headers(no - 1)               ' headers are zerobased
    Next no
'f) Enter year, month & month data in a loop
    Const START& = 2
    Dim i&, mon&, ii&
    ii = START - 1
    For i = START To UBound(arr2)
            mon = (i - START) Mod MONTHSCOUNT + 1   ' 0 to 11 (omitting 1 caption row) + 1
            If mon = 1 Then ii = ii + 1             ' increment data row of arr1 in January

           'arr2(i, 1) has already been prefilled by section [2]d)
            arr2(i, 2) = yr
            arr2(i, 3) = Application.Text(DateSerial(yr, mon, 1), "mmm")
            arr2(i, 4) = arr(ii, mon + COLUMNOFFSET)
    Next i


'~~~~~~~~~~~~ ~[3] Write back pivot base to any sheet (via CodeName) ~~~~~~~~~~~
With Sheet2
    .Range("A:D") = vbNullString
    .Range("A1").Resize(UBound(arr2), UBound(arr2, 2)) = arr2
End With
End Sub
```

**Helper function `getRowsArr()`**

```
Function getRowsArr(ByVal ItemsCount, Optional ByVal n& = 12) As Variant()
' Purpose: return 1-dim 0-based array containing n row numbers per item + title row no 1
' Note:    allows restructuring the original array to contain all months data
    Const START& = 2                        ' data rang starts in 2nd row
    Dim tmp(), i&, ii&
    ReDim tmp(0 To (ItemsCount - 1) * n)    ' includes header row number 1 at tmp(0) - zerobound!
'1) fill temporary array
    tmp(0) = 1                              ' title row no equals 1
    For i = START To ItemsCount             ' row no 2 to ...
        For ii = 0 To n - 1                 ' repeat row number n times
            tmp((i - START) * n + ii + 1) = i
        Next ii
    Next i
'2) return Array(1,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,3,........3,4...,...) as function value
    getRowsArr = tmp
    'Debug.Print Left$(Join(tmp, ","), 65) & "..."
End Function
```