# How to copy non contiguous columns and copy everything except first 2 and last 1 row without cut?Cutting takes long time when there is a lot of rows

Tags: excel, vba

How to copy non contiguous columns and copy everything except first 2 and last 1 row without cut?Cutting takes long time when there is a lot of rows.
I reorder an after copy.I want to copy without reordering for example copy  columns c,a,h,f,o,l everything except first 2 and last 1 row

```
Columns("F:F").Select
Selection.Cut
Columns("D:D").Select
Selection.Insert Shift:=xlToRight
Columns("F:F").Select
Selection.Cut
Columns("E:E").Select
Selection.Insert Shift:=xlToRight
Columns("T:T").Select
Selection.Cut
Columns("G:G").Select
Selection.Insert Shift:=xlToRight
Columns("I:I").Select
Selection.Cut
Columns("H:H").Select
Selection.Insert Shift:=xlToRight
Columns("J:J").Select
Selection.Cut
Columns("I:I").Select
Selection.Insert Shift:=xlToRight
ActiveWindow.SmallScroll Down:=69
ActiveWindow.LargeScroll Down:=-4
Range(Range("C3"), Range("I3").End(xlDown).Offset(-1, 0)).Select
Selection.Copy
```

Comment: Are you just reordering columns?

Comment: You might benefit from reading 
[How to avoid using Select in Excel VBA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10714251/how-to-avoid-using-select-in-excel-vba).

Comment: Yes,i reorder an after copy.I want to copy without reordering for example columns c,a,h,f  everything except first 2 and last 1 row

Comment: I'm presuming you are new to VBA? Short of writing the code for you (which might not make too much sense), apart from what @Pᴇʜ suggested, it might be worth doing a course on VBA

Comment: TL;DR - are you overwriting columns, i.e. all columns other than C,A,H,F and O resulting in these five columns left?

Answer (score 0):

**Rearranging columns via `Application.Index()` function**

This fast approach doesn't copy individual ranges, but uses arrays instead and demonstrates the advanced possibilities of the [`Application.Index()` function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51688593/excel-vba-insert-new-first-column-in-datafield-array-without-loops-or-api-call/51714153#51714153) allowing to **rearrange** the internal rows & columns structure by one single code line (~> see section `[3]` in the procedure `Sub Rearrange()` below).

This solution assumes that you want a new columns order consisting *only* of the five (original) data columns `C`,`A`,`H`,`F` and `O`, thus deleting all not included columns - but you can easily change the constant `NEWCOLUMNORDER` to *any* other combination, if you want to include further or *all* columns.

**Main procedure `Rearrange`**

```
Sub ReArrange()
With Sheet1             ' using the CodeName of a sheet, see (Name) in Property Tool Window
  Const NEWCOLUMNORDER As String = "C,A,H,F,O"
  ' [0] Define data range as well as first and last row (checking e.g. column A:A)
    Dim firstRow As Long, lastRow As Long
    firstRow = 3: lastRow = .Range("A" & .Rows.count).End(xlUp).Row
    Dim rng As Range
    Set rng = .Range("A" & firstRow & ":O" & lastRow - 1) ' start from 3rd row
  ' [1] assign data values to (1-based) 2-dimensional variant array
    Dim v As Variant
    v = rng.Value2
  ' [2] empty original data range (omitting last row)
    rng.Resize(lastRow - firstRow).Clear
  ' [3] Rearrange array rows & columns
    v = Application.Index(v, _
        Evaluate("row(1:" & lastRow - firstRow & ")"), _
        ColNos(NEWCOLUMNORDER))
  ' [4] Write array back to range
    rng.Resize(UBound(v), UBound(v, 2)) = v
End With
End Sub
```

Note that I prefer to use a sheet's unique `CodeName` associated to your VBA project (~> see the code line `With Sheet1`) avoiding for instance issues after sheets being renamed via sheet tab (by default starting with identical Name as its `CodeName` in the VBE Window with `(Name)` in brackets!). Of Course it's possible to refer to e.g. `With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")` too.

**Helper function `ColNos()`**

```
Function ColNos(ByVal s, Optional ByVal DELIM$ = ",") As Variant()
'Purpose: return array of column numbers
'Example: "C,A,H,F,O" ~~> Array(3,1,8,6,15)
s = Split(s, DELIM)         ' split string into individual column letters
ReDim tmp(0 To UBound(s))   ' define array's (1st) dimension via array indices
Dim i&                      ' zero based items counter
For i = 0 To UBound(s)      ' loop through column letters, e.g. C,A,H,F,O
    tmp(i) = Columns(s(i) & ":" & s(i)).Column ' get column number
Next i
ColNos = tmp                ' return temporary array items
End Function
```