# VBA array exporting to sheet

Tags: arrays, excel, vba

I have an array with values in it, and i want to paste several columns to two parts of the same sheet. First matrix would be pasted in column B and second in column H.

Is it possible to export several columns (not one and not all) with a single procedure?
So far i have the options below, i can export one or all of the columns but not "a few".

```
Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("B" & m).Resize(s, 14).Value = Matrix3 'Exports entire matrix
Worksheets("E02 Sheet2").Range("B" & o).Resize(t, 9).Value = Application.Index(Matrix, 0, 1) 'Exports a single column of a matrix
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Something like that is possible:
Let's assume we have a sheet like in the picture below
[image]

The following code will put the first and third column into the variable `vDat` and write it back.

```
Sub TestIt()
    Dim matrix As Variant
    matrix = Sheet1.Range("A1:C3")

    Dim vDat As Variant
    vDat = Application.Index(matrix, Array(1, 2, 3), Application.Transpose(Array(1, 3)))

    Sheet1.Range("E1").Resize(3, 2).Value = Application.Transpose(vDat)

End Sub
```

You "only" need to modify the code to your needs

Comment: FYI - I listed the advanced possibilities of the `Application.Index` function like filtering and restructuring already in a 2018 post [Array insertion without loops or API calls](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51688593/excel-vba-insert-new-first-column-in-datafield-array-without-loops-or-api-call/51714153#51714153); it's worth playing around with undiscovered or not so well known methods : +1)