# How to slice an array in batches in VBA

Tags: arrays, excel, vba, loops

Suppose I have a VBA one dimension array (or dict or collection) with X values. I need to perform an action with these values in batches of Y.

So if X = 55 and Y = 25, I would need to loop 3 times:

1. Pick values 1 to 25 and perform action
2. Pick values 26 to 50 and perform action
3. Pick last 5 values and perform action

Any ideas with good performance will be greatly appreciated :)

Edit:

I came up with the code below. It works although doesn't look very concise

```
Sub test()

Dim arr As Variant
Dim temparr As Variant
Dim sippno As Integer
Dim loopend As Integer
Dim loopstart As Integer
Dim batchsize As Integer
Dim i As Integer

'Storing main array with all values

arr = Sheet1.Range("A1:A" & Sheet1.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row).Value

'Setting count of values, batch size and starting step for loop

sippno = WorksheetFunction.CountA(arr)
loopstart = 1
batchsize = 10

Do Until sippno = 0

If sippno < batchsize Then
loopend = loopstart + sippno - 1
Else
loopend = loopstart + batchsize - 1
End If

ReDim temparr(loopstart To loopend)

For i = loopstart To loopend

temparr(i) = WorksheetFunction.Index(arr, i, 0)

sippno = sippno - 1

Next

loopstart = loopend + 1

'Action to be performed with batch of values stored in second array

Debug.Print WorksheetFunction.TextJoin(", ", True, temparr)

Loop

End Sub
```

Comment: What have you tried? Please edit your question and show us your code attempt.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Slicing via `Application.Index()`**

Just for the sake of the art I demonstrate in this late post how to slice a 'vertical' array *in one go* into several 'flat' arrays in batches of e.g. 10 elements.

This approach benefits from the advanced **rearranging** features & [pecularities of `Application.Index()`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51688593/excel-vba-insert-new-first-column-in-datafield-array-without-loops-or-api-call/51714153#51714153)
allowing to pass entire row/column number arrays as arguments; here suffices a vertical array of desired row numbers, e.g. by filtering only rows 11 to 20 via `Application.Index(data, Evaluate("Row(11:20)"), 0)`. *.. c.f. see section 2 a)*

*Further notes:*

- *evaluating* a tabular row formula is one quick way to get consecutive row numbers.
- *transposing* the function result changes the array dimension to a 1-dim array
- reducing the array *boundaries* by -1 via `ReDim Preserve ar(0 To UBound(ar) - 1)` produces a zero-based array (optional)

```
Option Explicit
Sub splice()
    Const batch = 10        ' act in units of 10 elements
    With Sheet1         
        '1) get data (1-based 2-dim array)
        Dim lastRow As Long
        lastRow = .Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
        Dim data: data = .Range("A1:A" & lastRow).Value2
        '2) slice
        Dim i As Long, nxt As Long, ar As Variant
        For i = 1 To UBound(data) Step batch
            nxt = Application.min(i + batch - 1, UBound(data))
            '2a) assign sliced data to 1- dim array (with optional redim to 0-base)
            With Application
                ar = .Transpose(.Index(data, Evaluate("row(" & i & ":" & nxt & ")")))
            End With
            'optional redimming to zero-base
            ReDim Preserve ar(0 To UBound(ar) - 1)  
            
            '2b) perform some action
            Debug.Print _
                "batch " & i \ batch + 1 & ": " & _
                "ar(" & LBound(ar) & " To " & UBound(ar) & ") ~~> " & _
                Join(ar, "|")
        Next
    End With
End Sub
```

**Slicing a 'flat' 1-dim array**

If, however you want to slice a 1-dim array, like e.g. dictionary keys, it suffices to transpose the data input: `data = Application.Transpose(...)`

Comment: @wwhitman Fyi A similar question focusses on how to spread a flat array into columns at [Reading array onto cells](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65293125/why-when-reading-my-array-onto-cells-in-vba-does-it-repeat-every-row/65327917#65327917)

Answer (score 2):

```vb
Option Explicit
Sub splice()

    Const batch = 10
   
    Dim data, ar()
    Dim lastrow As Long, n As Long, i As Long
    Dim j As Long, r As Long
   
    With Sheet1
        lastrow = .Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
        data = .Range("A1:A" & lastrow).Value2
    End With
    i = Int(lastrow / batch)
   
    For n = 0 To i
        r = batch
        If n = i Then
            r = lastrow Mod batch
        End If
        If r > 0 Then
            ReDim ar(r - 1)
            For j = 1 To r
                ar(j - 1) = data(j + n * batch, 1)
            Next
            ' do something
            Debug.Print Join(ar, ",")
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

2d array because to lazy to encode 1d but same idea with 1d:

```
Sub test()
    arr = Sheet3.Range("A1").CurrentRegion.Value2
    x = UBound(arr)
    y = 5
    jj = y
    
    For j = 1 To UBound(arr)
        sumaction = sumaction + arr(j, 1)
        If (UBound(arr) - jj) < 0 Then
            jj = UBound(arr)
            sumaction = 0
        End If
        If j = jj Then
            dosomething = sumaction * 2
            sumaction = 0
            jj = jj + y
        End If
    Next j
End Sub
```