# Transposing Data from one workbook to another depending on column heading

Tags: excel, vba

I have code below which transposes column values from one particular workbook (Activeworkbook - columns O,AH and I) over to another workbook ("loader file.xls" - columns A,B,C). It works perfectly for my needs

```
Sub PullTrackerInfo()
'Pull info from respective column into correct column on loader file

Dim wb_mth As Workbook, wb_charges As Workbook, mapFromColumn As Variant, mapToColumn As Variant
    Dim lastCell As Integer, i As Integer, nextCell As Integer, arrCopy As Variant
Set wb_mth = ActiveWorkbook
Set wb_charges = Workbooks("loader file.xls")
    

    mapFromColumn = Array("O", "AH", "I")
    mapToColumn = Array("A", "B", "C")

        For i = 0 To UBound(mapFromColumn)

            With wb_mth.Sheets(1)

                lastCell = w.Sheets("owssvr").ListObjects("Table_owssvr").Range.Rows.Count
                arrCopy = .Range(mapFromColumn(i) & 2 & ":" & mapFromColumn(i) & lastCell)

            End With

            With wb_charges.Worksheets(1)

                nextCell = .Range(mapToColumn(i) & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row + 1
                .Range(mapToColumn(i) & nextCell).Resize(UBound(arrCopy), UBound(arrCopy, 2)).Value = arrCopy

            End With
        Next i

End Sub
```

What I would like to do is to go one step further, I typically have to sort the data to the correct column in order to transpose it over to the loader file. What I would like to do is move the columns data over depending on the title of the column heading ("market Code, "ID", "C Code"). See the idea below...

```
mapFromColumn = Array("Market Code", "ID", "C Code",
    mapToColumn = Array("A", "B", "C")

        For i = 0 To UBound(mapFromColumn)

            With wb_mth.Sheets(1)

                lastCell = w.Sheets("owssvr").ListObjects("Table_owssvr").Range.Rows.Count
                arrCopy = .Range(mapFromColumn(i) & 2 & ":" & mapFromColumn(i) & lastCell)

            End With

            With wb_charges.Worksheets(1)

                nextCell = .Range(mapToColumn(i) & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row + 1
                .Range(mapToColumn(i) & nextCell).Resize(UBound(arrCopy), UBound(arrCopy, 2)).Value = arrCopy

            End With
        Next i

End Sub
```

The code above does not obviously work, i've tried a couple of different tactics to no avail. If anyone could help me out that would be great. Thanks

Comment: If you recalculate `nextCell` for each column, instead of using the same value for all of them, there's a chance you'll end up with mis-aligned data if any of your columns have blanks at the end...

Comment: @Cleanrider Posted a possible solution to your issue using a rather unknown feature of `Application.Match()` to get all wanted column numbers of individual headers at once (assuming existing headers).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Write rearranged listobject columns to target**

This approach uses

- a rather unknown feature of `Application.Match()` to get all **column numbers** of individual headers *at once* by a comparison of two arrays (assuming existing headers, otherwise it would need extra error handling) as well as
- the advanced feature of `Application.Index()` to **rearrange** the whole listbox data set based on the found *numeric column* values *(whereas row values are taken completely and in unchanged order)*.

```
Function getCols(individualHeaders, myTable As ListObject)
'Note: assumes existing header names & listobject start in column A
    'get all headers of list object
    Dim allHeaders
    allHeaders = Application.Transpose(myTable.HeaderRowRange.Value2)
    'get column numbers of found headers
    Dim cols
    cols = Application.Match(individualHeaders, allHeaders, 0)  ' 1-based
    ReDim Preserve cols(0 To UBound(cols) - 1)                  ' optional zero-base redim
    'return found numeric results
    getCols = cols
End Function
```

**Example code**

Though there are some undeclared worksheet references in OP, this should work & solve your question

```
'[0]set listobject to memory
    Dim lob As ListObject
    Set lob = w.Sheets("owssvr").ListObjects("Table_owssvr")
'[1]get column numbers
    Dim mapFromColumn As Variant
    mapFromColumn = Array("Market Code", "ID", "C Code")
    mapFromColumn = getCols(mapFromColumn, lob)
    ' Debug.Print Join(mapFromColumn, ",")
'[2]get complete set of listobject data
    Dim data As Variant
    data = lob.DataBodyRange.Value2
'[3]limit data set to chosen columns in subsequent order
    data = Application.Index(data, Evaluate("row(1:" & UBound(data) & ")"), mapFromColumn)
'[4]write data to target
    Dim wb_charges As Workbook
    Set wb_charges = Workbooks("loader file.xls")
    With wb_charges.Worksheets(1)
        Dim nextCell As Long
        nextCell = .Range("A" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row + 1 
        .Range("A" & nextCell).Resize(UBound(data), UBound(data, 2)).Value = data
    End With
```

**Related link**

- [Some pecularities of the `Application.Index()` function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51688593/excel-vba-insert-new-first-column-in-datafield-array-without-loops-or-api-call/51714153#51714153)

Answer (score 0):

If you recalculate nextCell for each column, instead of using the same value for all of them, there's a chance you'll end up with mis-aligned data if any of your columns have blanks at the end.

You can reference the source table columns using `ListColumns(columnName)` so something like this should work (untested):

```vb
Dim lo As ListObject, wsDest As Worksheet, numRows As Long

'...
'...

Set wsDest = wb_charges.Worksheets(1)
Set lo = w.Sheets("owssvr").ListObjects("Table_owssvr")
numRows = lo.DataBodyRange.Rows.Count

mapFromColumn = Array("Market Code", "ID", "C Code")
mapToColumn = Array("A", "B", "C")

'start all destinations on the same row (choose a column with no blanks in the data...)
nextcell = wsDest.Cells(wsDest.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row + 1
    
For i = 0 To UBound(mapFromColumn)
    wsDest.Cells(nextcell, mapToColumn(i)).Resize(numRows).Value = _
        lo.ListColumns(mapFromColumn(i)).DataBodyRange.Value
Next i
```

Comment: hi Tim, the nextcell issue hasnt really been a problem to be honest