# Making a list of Names based on a status number in excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have an Excel file that has two main columns a Name column and a Status column. The values in the Name column are all unique values and the values in the status column are numerical 1-5. Is there a formula to show which names are in which status? Additionally, this list is only 40-60 entries at a time so solutions that are not efficient would still work for this case.

Example of rows:

| Name | Status |
| --- | --- |
| B34 | 2 |
| F92 | 4 |
| H92 | 3 |
| C02 | 2 |
| G50 | 2 |
| Q459 | 5 |

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`=FILTER(A:A, B:B=1)`

will return all names that have status 1,

`=FILTER(A:A, B:B=2)` status 2,

`=FILTER(A:A, B:B=3)` status 3,

etc. Hope it helps

Comment: Is there a package that is needed to use the filter formula?  It says that function isn't valid when I attempt to use it

Comment: Since you did not specify your Excel type or version, I wrote on Excel 365. For office excel, refer to this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67474397/alternative-of-filter-function-on-non-office-365