# Filter data from a cell (using formula)

Tags: excel

I'm using Ms Excel 2016 (the filter function doesn't exist).
I'm working on a file for recording and assigning equipment and materials to staff.
[Record table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yvXLw.png)
I want to dynamically filter the equipment by category so that when the assignment table is filled in, when a category is chosen, its equipment appears in a drop-down list.
[Allocation table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/03bqC.png)
Thx

I've tried to create named range, but not working

Comment: Try searching `Stackoverflow` with `INDEX()` & `AGGREGATE()` multiple times it has been solved. Look at this link specifically it will help, **[Filter_Alternative](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67474397/alternative-of-filter-function-on-non-office-365?rq=1)**