# How can I return multiple employee training record from a huge dataset. Currently I'm only getting one return value using a VLOOKUP

Tags: arrays, excel, excel-formula, vlookup, multiple-records

I'm looking to search a user ID and have the return show all training that is in the current dataset..I have included a small snap shot to show what I mean.

[image]

I've used a VLOOKUP but it's only returning the one value.

I'm thinking an INDEX MATCH but I'm unsure if it will work. Someone suggested an IFERROR instead?

Comment: Does your version of Excel support FILTER?

Comment: If you dont have `FILTER()` function then look at this link : **[here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67474397/alternative-of-filter-function-on-non-office-365?rq=1)**

Comment: Unfortunately I don't have the version which supports FILTER. I'll have a look at that video link just now though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is an array formula, so confirming the formula with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd>.

Please try.

```
=IFERROR(INDEX($E$2:$E$6, SMALL(IF($A$2:$A$6=I$1, ROW($A$2:$A$6)-1,""), ROW(1:99)), 1), "")
```

[image]

Microsoft reference document:

> [Guidelines and examples of array formulas](https://support.microsoft.com/en-au/office/guidelines-and-examples-of-array-formulas-7d94a64e-3ff3-4686-9372-ecfd5caa57c7#:%7E:text=An%20array%20formula%20is%20a,results%2C%20or%20a%20single%20result.?WT.mc_id=M365-MVP-33461)