# Deleting Non-Contiguous Range Based on Blank Cells

Tags: excel, vba, loops, range, cell

I want my code to take a user defined range and delete any blank cells as well as the cell one to the right of the blank cell.
[image: For instance]

Here is what I have so far:

```
Sub CleanupAccountsinYear()

Dim selectedrng As Range

Range(Selection, Selection).Select

Set selectedrng = Application.Selection


For Each Cell In selectedrng

    If Cell.Value = "" Then
    Cell.Activate
    Range(ActiveCell, Cells((ActiveCell.Row), (ActiveCell.Column) + 1)).Select
    'Missing Vital Component
    End If
         
Next Cell
End Sub
```

The problem is that each time I delete the selected range and the macro moves on to the next cell it will skip a cell. My thinking is I may have to store the ranges in a union and delete them from there but that has proven to be a bit difficult.  Is there an easier way to solve this?

Comment: If you are deleting cells you need to iterate from the last cell to the first. If you go from 1 to n, you will skip every other cell. Basically make your For loop like this: For row = totalRows to 1 step -1

Comment: @SnowGroomer so I should delete the loop dealing with cells?

Comment: I have posted my suggestion as an answer - this way it will be clearer what I meant, I hope.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is how I would generally approach deleting rows where the first column is empty.
Notice that the for loops iterates backwards - this eliminates row skipping observed when iterated forwards from 1 to row count.

```
Sub RemoveRowsWithBlankFirstColumn()
  Dim rng As Range
  Set rng = Application.Selection
  Dim i As Integer
  For i = rng.Rows.Count To 1 Step -1
    If rng.Cells(i, 1).Value2 = vbNullString Then
      rng.Cells(i, 1).EntireRow.Delete
    End If
  Next i
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

> Is there an **easier** way to solve this?

If you dispose of MS/Excel 365 (see [`FILTER` formula](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/filter-function-f4f7cb66-82eb-4767-8f7c-4877ad80c759)) and assuming 2 column ranges you can profit from the new dynamic array features by

- Step 1..2 evaluating the *Excel formula* `FILTER` *(vs. MS/Excel 365)*,
- Step 3    rearranging the array values of the data range via [`Application.Index()`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51688593/excel-vba-insert-new-first-column-in-datafield-array-without-loops-or-api-call/51714153#51714153) and
- Step 4    overwriting the original data

as follows:

```
Sub ExcludeBlanks(rng As Range)
'1. build individual formula
    Dim myFormula As String: myFormula = "FILTER(ROW($),$<>0,"""")"
    myFormula = Replace(myFormula, "$", rng.Address(False, False, external:=True))
'2. get array of row numbers to maintain
    Dim rowNums: rowNums = Evaluate(myFormula)
'3. a) get data (consisting of 2 columns)
    Dim data:    data = rng.Resize(ColumnSize:=2).Value2
'   b) rearrange data (based on rowNums to maintain & first two columns)
    data = Application.Index(data, rowNums, Array(1, 2))
'4. overwrite original range by rearranged data (INDEX)
    rng.Clear
    rng.Resize(UBound(data), UBound(data, 2)) = data
End Sub
```

**Note** to prior versions of MS/Excel

Of course you can also build a (vertical) 2-dimensional array by looping through the original data isolating element/row numbers of non-blanks:-)