# Excel VBA split after second space

Tags: excel, vba, split

I'm trying to split my column so that the names

James John Doe

Comes out as only

James John

Using the below formula but it only leaves the first name, where I want it to split at the second occurrence of "space".

```
Sub Split1()
Dim r As Range

For Each r In Range("A2:A" & Cells(Rows.count, "A").End(xlUp).Row).Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants)
    r.Value = Split(r.Value, " ")(0)
    
Next r
```

Can anyone help me out?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may try to use `left & find` to obtain the string value untill second space instead of `split` function

Code modification:

```
Dim r As Range
Dim s As String, newText As String
Dim Length As Long

For Each r In Range("A2:A" & Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row).Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants)
    s = r.Value
    Length = Application.WorksheetFunction.Find(" ", s, Application.WorksheetFunction.Find(" ", s) + 1)
    
    r.Value = Left(s, Length)
Next r
```

Sample output:

[image]

Comment: This worked fantastically, thanks a ton Kin!

Comment: Welcome, similar to excel function :)

Comment: `VBA` has its own functions e.g. to get the number of characters before the second occurrence of a space use `Length = InStr(InStr(1, s, " ") + 1, s, " ")` (similar to your solution) or to get the number of characters before the last occurrence of a space use `Length = InStrRev(s, " ") - 1)`.

Comment: @VBasic2008, ya i never know `instr` work like find, anyway I am happy with `find` function in excel, both can be interchanged to use

Answer (score 2):

There are a few ways you can turn a *three-word phrase* into the first two words.

Let's start with your `Split()` method.
This function returns an array. Your particular method of attempting to access the index will only return a single word.

You can place into an array, then just combine the array elements:

```
For Each r In Range(...)

    Dim retVal() As String
    retVal = Split(r.Value)
    r.Value = retVal(0) & " " & retVal(1)

Next r
```

You can remove the last word with `Replace()`:

```
For Each r In Range(...)

    r.Value = Replace(r.Value, Split(r.Value)(2), "")

Next
```

Or you can even use Regular Expressions:

```
With CreateObject("VBScript.RegExp")

    .Pattern = "\s[^\s]+$"
    For Each r in Range(...)
        r.Value = .Replace(r.Value, "")
    Next
    
End With
```

In Regular Expressions, `\s` signifies a single space character, the `[^...]` bracket means "Do not include", which we placed a `\s` within the bracket, so that would match any *non-space character*, followed by the `+` means 1 or more times, and finally the `$` signifies the end of the string. Essentially, you are wanting to match a word `[^\s]+` that is at the end of the string `$`, preceeded by a space `\s`, and remove it via the `.Replace()` method. And you actually could also simply use the pattern `\s\S+$`, which is essentially the same thing (`\S` means any non-space character when it's capitalized).

Comment: Thanks K.David! I learnt a lot form this, tried them all out and they work perfectly. I was wondering, though, if there is a way for the last word to also be changed to a single character in your retval or pattern method? To change James John Doe to James J?

Comment: Yeah you can just change the last part of the line to `Left(retVal(1), 1)`.

Comment: @KelvinC if you wanted to use the pattern method, you could replace the .Pattern line with: `.Pattern = "^(\S+\s\w).*"` and the replace line with `r.Value = .Replace(r.Value, "$1")`

Comment: And btw, if you want you can visualize and learn more about this exact regular expression and how it works, you can click here: [Your customized RegEx link by Regex101.com](https://regex101.com/r/MAGlHJ/1). There's an explanation section on this site to the right that you can review.

Comment: @K.Dᴀᴠɪs Loved your helpful overview :+); fyi posted a late approach just to enrich the choice of posted & valid solutions.

Answer (score 1):

**Further way to extract the 1st and 3rd token of a split array**

This approach profits from the advanced possibilities of [Application.Index](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51688593/excel-vba-insert-new-first-column-in-datafield-array-without-loops-or-api-call/51714153#51714153) allowing to indicate any new row or columns order; the wanted columns are reflected here by the last 1-based (columns) argument `Array(1, 3)`:

```
Function GetFirstLast(s As String) As String
    GetFirstLast = Join(Application.Index(Split(s), 0, Array(1, 3)))
End Function
```

**Example call:**

`Debug.Print GetFirstLast("James John Doe")`

resulting in

`James Doe` in the VB Editor's immediate window.

Comment: Nice approach on this one. Would have never thought to use this

Comment: Thanks for the feedback; indeed, `Application.Index()` offers a whole universe of restructuring possibilities for 1-dim as well as 2-dim arrays *(c.f. indicated post listing [some pecularities](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51688593/excel-vba-insert-new-first-column-in-datafield-array-without-loops-or-api-call/51714153#51714153))*. Note that `Application.Index` returns arrays 1-based (in case of 2-dim arrays it re-bases both dimensions). @K.Dᴀᴠɪs