# Excel VBA Insert New Row into an Array

Tags: arrays, excel, vba, insert, row

I have a 2D Array and I want to insert a number of rows in the middle of the array at some row number.

The Array already has existing information, so ReDim Preserve doesn't quite work if i wanted to simply place the new information in the middle.

Any ideas?

Comment: create a new array of the size desired, loop the first array and put the values where you want.

Comment: Copy to an `ArrayList` or `Dictionary`.  Add the new items where you want them. Then recreate an array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming two **1-based** 2-dim datafield inputs, I demonstrate an alternative to @FaneDuru's valid approach using a solitary **combo list** creation as *data container* and allowing a simple item insertion via the now disponible `.AddItem` *method*.

**Note** that of course this approach can be refined in many directions, *e.g. by allowing different index bases for input arrays*. - **Methodical hint:** Assigning the zero-based combo's `.Column` property (i.e. the inverted `.List` prop) and transposing it back allows here to regain the original one-based indexing of the input array as a `ReDim Preserve` would fail *(it can only redim the last dimension)*.

```
Sub AddElement(datafield, ByVal rowNum As Long, newData)
'Note: assumes 1-based 2dim input arrays with same column counts
'create zero-based combo container on the fly
With CreateObject("Forms.ComboBox.1")
    .list = datafield     ' assign datafield to zero-based list elems
    .AddItem , rowNum - 1 ' add Null values to zero-based list index
    'assign new data to each zero-based list column
        Dim col As Long
        For col = LBound(newData, 2) To UBound(newData, 2)
            .list(rowNum - 1, col - 1) = newData(1, col)
        Next col
    'overwrite original datafield with transposed list values to regain 1-based elems
    datafield = Application.Transpose(.Column)    ' overwriting data (with zerobased dimensions)
End With

End Sub
```

As the `datafield` argument is passed implicitly by reference (`ByRef`), the original data input will be overwritten.

**Example Call with insertion of a new 2nd row**

```
Dim data:    data = Sheet1.Range("A1:C4").Value
Dim newData: newData = Sheet2.Range("A1:C1").Value
AddElement data, 2, newData
```

Comment: Feel free to study as well Fane Duru's tricky answer upvoting it if instructive or helpful @B-M

Comment: Very interesting! Voted it up. I do  not know if this can be used without array size limitations, but nice idea. I think it can be improved to not need any `Application.Transpose`, which it is known that it has size limitations. I have an idea and I (think) know what `list` property could not be used instead of transposed `.column`. No time now to deal with it, but if what I have in mind will be covered by reality and I can do it in 5 - 10 minutes, I will post a new answer showing it. Anyhow, nice approach...

Answer (score 1):

In replay to @T.M. nice approach:

Try using the next function, which does not need transposing of column array:

```
Function AddElement(datafield, ByVal rowNum As Long, newData) As Variant
    'Note: assumes 1-based 2dim input arrays with same column counts
    'create zero-based combo container on the fly
    With CreateObject("Forms.ComboBox.1")
        .list = datafield     ' assign datafield to zero-based list elems
        .AddItem , rowNum - 1 ' add Null values to zero-based list index
        'assign new data to each zero-based list column
            Dim col As Long
            For col = LBound(newData, 2) To UBound(newData, 2)
                .list(rowNum - 1, col - 1) = newData(1, col)
            Next col
        AddElement = .list 'it returns a zero based 2D array...
    End With
End Function
```

It can be tested in this way:

```
Sub testAddArrayrow()
 Dim sh As Worksheet, newArr: sh = ActiveSheet  'was easier for me to check...
 Dim data:    data = sh.Range("A1:C4").Value
 Dim newData: newData = sh.Range("A6:C6").Value
    newArr = AddElement(data, 2, newData)
    sh.Range("P1").Resize(UBound(newArr) + 1, UBound(newArr, 2) + 1).Value = newArr '+ 1 because of zero bazed 2D returned array
End Sub
```

We must make some researches in order to check the array size limitations, if any. It will be very interesting to not have such limitations, but I simply cannot hope too much from this direction... :)

Anyhow, the brilliant idea remains...

Comment: If the intention is to rewrite the (now *zero*-based) data to a sheet range without need to stick to the original 1-based datafield, returning the `.List` results is clearly the preferred way *(btw my original approach)*.  Anyway it's interesting that writing data back doesn't care about boundaries @FaneDuru :)

Comment: @T.M. I think I understood the reason you used `.column` property and I only tried  showing how such a returned array can be dropped on a range.

Answer (score 0):

Please, try the next way:

```
Sub TestInsertRow()
    Dim sh, arr, arrInsR, arrFin
    
    Set sh = ActiveSheet
    arr = sh.[A1:C5].Value       'array to insert a row
    arrInsR = sh.[A11:C11].Value 'row to be inserted
    arrFin = InsertRowElab(arr, arrInsR, 3) 'inserted row to be the third
   sh.[J10].Resize(UBound(arrFin), UBound(arrFin, 2)).Value = arrFin
End Sub

Private Function InsertRowElab(arr As Variant, arrIns As Variant, insRowNo As Long) As Variant 'it inserts a row
   Dim i&, k&, Ar, arrR, arrRows, arrCols
   
   arrR = Application.Transpose(Application.Evaluate("row(1:" & UBound(arr) & ")")) 'build the rows array
    Debug.Print "Joined rows array: " & Join(arrR, "#"):                                        'so the joined array looks
   arrRows = Split(Replace(Join(arrR, "|"), insRowNo - 1 & "|", insRowNo - 1 & "|0|"), "|")      'insert the row, placing 0 in the array
    Debug.Print "Joined rows array containing the inserted row (0): " & Join(arrRows, "#")       'so the joined array containing the new row (0) looks
   arrCols = Application.Transpose(Application.Evaluate("row(1:" & UBound(arr, 2) & ")")) 'Array(1, 2, 3)
   Ar = Application.Index(arr, Application.Transpose(arrRows), arrCols)
   'fill the inserted row:
   For i = LBound(Ar) To UBound(Ar, 2): Ar(insRowNo, i) = arrIns(1, i): Next i
   InsertRowElab = Ar
End Function
```

Comment: Just FYI this will not work with large arrays because of the limitations of transpose.

Comment: @Scott Craner I know about its limitations. In case of large arrays, `Transpose` function limitations can be solved using a custom transpose function, being comparable fast. Easy to be written. I only tried showing a way to insert a row (it can be adapted to insert a slice of more rows) in a 2D array, as it was requested in the question. Just for the sake of showing how to be done...

Comment: Nicely done and a very tricky roundabout way to get the new order of array rows (`arrRows`) by a consecutive *join*, *replace* and *split* action +:) - It might make it easier for other users to understand this approach having a look at [Some peculiarities of the the `Application.Index` function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51688593/excel-vba-insert-new-first-column-in-datafield-array-without-loops-or-api-call/51714153#51714153) @FaneDuru

Comment: @T.M.  I have a **friend** here with whom I debated he issue... :)

Comment: Appreciate your always valuable solutions and contributions. - Fyi As you, too like *alternatives*, you might be interested in my post demonstrating a combo list vehicle. @FaneDuru

Comment: @T.M. Where should I see the mentioned post? Did you forget to place a link?

Comment: It's in the same post as a further [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68777731/excel-vba-insert-new-row-into-an-array/68786557#68786557)  @FaneDuru