# Is there an easy way to add a string to beginning and end of VBA array

Tags: excel, vba

If i have this code is there a simple way to add item1 to the beginning of the array and item2 to the end of the array in VBA?

The below code currently runs.

```
Dim nameArray as variant
Dim k as integer
Dim item1 as string
Dim item2 as string

k = 1
nameArray = Range(Cells(2, 3), Cells(5, 3)).Value
    For Each i In nameArray
        newcol = baseclmn + k
        tblComp.ListColumns.Add(newcol).Name = i
        k = k + 1
    Next I
```

Thanks for any help you can offer

Comment: `nameArray(1, 1) = "item1"`, `nameArray(Ubound(nameArray, 1), UBound(nameArray, 2)) = "item2"`

Comment: That sort of works but it appears to cut off some items. The range contains 4 values that are loaded into the array. Afterwords there should be six total when 1 is added to the beginning and end. However there appears to be only 4. Also does all that code go on one line?

Comment: Ah you need to expand the array. Probably easiest to create a new array, add in the first and last items (similar to the provided code), then read the 4 items into the middle of the array.

Comment: Are you able to expand on how to do that? This is my first time using an array in VBA. Thank you for your help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could start off with a larger array and replace the first and last items.

```vb
Dim nameArray as variant

nameArray = Range(Cells(1, 3), Cells(6, 3)).Value

nameArray(LBound(nameArray), 1) = "Item1"
nameArray(UBound(nameArray), 1) = "Item2"
```

Comment: Yah this is probably easier lol. Though this approach will obviously break if the data to be read starts in row 1.

Comment: Thats an interesting and clever idea. It appears to work perfectly. Can you explain what you mean when you say it will break? I appreciate your explanation on your answer as well that's hugely helpful. Edit: Oh I understand now. My table has a header so that will not be an issue

Comment: This is brilliant

Answer (score 2):

If you want to expand the array, perhaps something like this:

```
nameArray = Range(Cells(2, 3), Cells(5, 3)).Value

Dim newArray
ReDim newArray(1 to Ubound(nameArray, 1) + 2, 1 to Ubound(nameArray, 2)) 'add two rows

newArray(1, 1) = "item1"
newArray(Ubound(newArray, 1), 1) = "item2"

Dim i As Long
For i = LBound(nameArray, 1) To Ubound(nameArray, 1)
   newArray(i + 1, 1) = nameArray(i, 1)
Next
```

---

Explanation:

`nameArray` is a 2-dimensional array, where the first dimension corresponds to rows and the second to columns. Note that this array is one-based, i.e. the first index is `1` and not `0`.

The code uses `ReDim` to create a new array, containing

- Two more rows than `nameArray`
- The same number of columns as `nameArray`.

Then it adds the first and last items:

- `newArray(1, 1) = "item1"`: `1, 1` corresponds to the first row, first column.
- `newArray(Ubound(newArray, 1), 1) = "item2"`: `Ubound(newArray, 1)` corresponds to the *last* row, and `1` again corresponds to the first column.

Finally it uses a loop to read the items from `nameArray` into the middle of `newArray`.

---

Further helpful reading includes [Arrays and Ranges in VBA](http://www.cpearson.com/excel/ArraysAndRanges.aspx).

Comment: That works perfectly! Are you able to explain a bit how it works? Im trying to learn

Comment: @Manuel added an explanation. Lmk if anything is still unclear.

Answer (score 1):

You can enlarge (and/or restructure) the existing (vertical) `nameArray` *in one go*

- via an [undocumented feature of `Application.Index()`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51688593/excel-vba-insert-new-first-column-in-datafield-array-without-loops-or-api-call/51714153#51714153)
- using either the new `Sequence()` function (available since MS 365!) or a workaround via row evaluation (commented out in comment)

to pass a whole array(!) of row numbers (`rowArr`) as argument *(instead of a single row index)*:

```
    newArray = Application.Index(nameArray, rowArr, 1)
```

where `rowArr` is a vertical array of sequential row numbers reflecting the currently existing indices, and `1` the unchanged column index.

```
Sub TopBottomAdditions()
'0. define 1-based 2-dim data field 
    Dim nameArray
    nameArray = Sheet1.Range(Cells(2, 3), Cells(5, 3)).Value 'i.e. data field of cells C2:C5
'1a create a sequence (array) ranging from 0 to elements count plus +1 (2 new elems)
    Dim rowArr              ' {0,1,2,..n,n+1}
    rowArr = WorksheetFunction.Sequence(UBound(nameArray) + 2, 1, 0)
    ''>workaround if you don't dispose of version MS 365
    '  rowArr = Evaluate("row(1:" & UBound(nameArray) + 2 & ")-1")
'1b keep existing values in rows 1..n and add top+bottom element
    'note: index 0 fetches element of existing index 1, n+1 gets a temporary error value
    Dim newArray
    newArray = Application.Index(nameArray, rowArr, 1)
'1c insert new top & bottom values
    newArray(1, 1) = "Top value"                    ' overwrites New elem no 1
    newArray(UBound(newArray), 1) = "Bottom value"  ' writes New last elem
End Sub
```

> **Syntax of Sequence()**

```
   =SEQUENCE(rows,[columns],[start],[step])
```