# Extract data from between characters

Tags: excel, vba, extract

there was a similar question answered but in practice it doesn't quite work. I don't know if there is a better way to accomplish my task.
I need to extract the data between "(" and the third "," for example
`$$ Data_out(3,47,0,40,0,0,2,8.01)` and having the result be `3,47,0` I will add below what I've tried

```
Dim str As String
Dim openPos As Integer
Dim closePos As Integer
Dim midBit As String
ActiveSheet.Range("A2").Activate
Do While Range("A:A").Cells(i, 1).Value <> ""

 On Error Resume Next
openPos = InStr(str, "(")
 On Error Resume Next
closePos = InStr(str, ",0,")
 On Error Resume Next
midBit = Mid(str, openPos + 1, closePos - openPos - 1)
extract_value = midBit

ActiveCell.Value = midBit

i = i + 1
Loop
```

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/split-function

Comment: How does your code work at all when you don't define `str`?

Comment: it was the first definition...

Comment: No that is not a definition, that is a declaration. You need to read braX's link. Neither do you define `i`. Those On Error lines are just masking all the problems.

Comment: so i declared 'i' as long, how should i define 'str'? as you can tell im really not well versed in vba

Comment: You have to assign it a value, i.e. `i=2`.

Answer (score 2):

Different approach:

```vb
Sub Tester()
    Dim txt, txt2, arr
    txt = "$$ Data_out(3,47,0,40,0,0,2,8.01)" 'input...
    txt2 = Split(txt, "(")(1)                 'everything after first "("
    arr = Split(txt2, ",")                    'split on comma
    ReDim Preserve arr(0 To 2)                'first 3 elements only
    Debug.Print Join(arr, ",")                'join to string
End Sub
```

Comment: Just for fun: instead of `ReDim Preserve` you might indicate an index array of the wanted 1-based output order  via `arr = Application.Index(arr, 0, Array(1, 2, 3))`. *Side note: this order can be changed.* C.f.: [Some pecularities of `Application.Index()`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51688593/excel-vba-insert-new-first-column-in-datafield-array-without-loops-or-api-call) @TimWilliams

Answer (score 1):

Read some VBA tutorials to master the basics.

Here's an alternative which use the worksheet function `Substitute` which has an instance parameter so you can pick out the third comma.

```
Sub x()

Dim str As String
Dim openPos As Long, closePos As Long
Dim midBit As String
Dim r As Long

For r = 2 To Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    openPos = InStr(Cells(r, 1), "(")
    str = WorksheetFunction.Substitute(Cells(r, 1), ",", "@", 3) '@ or any character not likely to appear in your data
    closePos = InStr(str, "@")
    If openPos > 0 And Len(str) > 0 Then
        midBit = Mid(str, openPos + 1, closePos - openPos - 1)
        Cells(r, 1).Value = midBit
    End If
Next r

End Sub
```

Comment: Maybe `str` shouldn't be used as a variable name either, since that shadows the [`Str`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/str-function) function?

Comment: that worked! thank you, i'll be sure to pay attention to the changes and learn a thing or two. thank you again!