# Array values not appearing when posted in Excel sheet

Tags: arrays, excel, vba

So I  am running this code

```
Sub Array_testing()

    Dim TestArray As Variant
    Dim OutputArray As Variant
    Dim OutputX As Variant
    Dim OutputY As Variant
    Dim InputX As Variant
    Dim InputY As Variant
    
    OutputX = 1
    OutputY = 1
    InputX = 1
    InputY = 2
    
    ReDim OutputArray(3, 5)
    
    TestArray = Range("a1:e3").Value

    Range("a6:e8").Value = TestArray
    
    Range("g1").Value = TestArray(2, 4)
        
    While InputX <> 4
            Debug.Print "output (" & OutputX & "," & OutputY & ") - input (" & InputX & "," & InputY & ")"
            OutputArray(OutputX, OutputY) = TestArray(InputX, InputY)
            Debug.Print OutputArray(OutputX, OutputY)
            OutputY = OutputY + 1
            InputY = InputY + 1
            If OutputY = 6 Then
                OutputX = OutputX + 1
                OutputY = 1
                InputX = InputX + 1
            End If
            If InputY = 6 Then
                InputY = 1
            End If
    Wend

    Range("a10:e12").Value = OutputArray
    Range("g2").Value = OutputArray(2, 1)
     
End Sub
```

and using these as my array values:

[image]

when the code hits **"Range("a10:e12").Value = OutputArray"**, this is what I get

[image]

when I am expecting this to show up

[image]

I know that the array values are entering correctly because when I specifically call the array location (for example OutputArray(1,2) I get Red, which is as expected.

And when I put the TestArray values in, they come up perfect.  It's the same call but for a different array, and the values are in the proper allocation spots, so why is it not showing up when I display the values of OutputArray?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Arrays in VBA are by default zero-based, so

```
ReDim OutputArray(3, 5)
```

is the same as

```
ReDim OutputArray(0 To 3, 0 To 5)
```

Your array is larger than you think, so you'd need A10:F13 to show the whole content.  The parts of your array which don't fit into the specified range will not be displayed.

1-based arrays are simpler to deal with if you're going to be putting them into a range on a worksheet, so:

```
ReDim OutputArray(1 To 3, 1 To 5)
```

Answer (score 1):

### Shift Array Columns

[image]

- All your issues are covered in Tim Williams' answer.
- Here's an example of how you could solve your task by using a `For...Next` loop which in my opinion is more straightforward than using a `Do Loop`.

```vb
Sub ArrayTest1()

    Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws = ActiveSheet ' improve!
    
    Dim srg As Range: Set srg = ws.Range("A1:E3")
    
    Dim sData(): sData = srg.Value
    
    Dim dData(): ReDim dData(1 To UBound(sData, 1), 1 To UBound(sData, 2))
    
    Dim r As Long, c As Long
    
    For r = 1 To UBound(sData, 1)
        For c = 1 To UBound(sData, 2) - 1
            dData(r, c) = sData(r, c + 1)
        Next c
        dData(r, c) = sData(r, 1)
    Next r
    
    Dim dfCell As Range: Set dfCell = ws.Range("A10")
    Dim drg As Range: Set drg = dfCell.Resize(UBound(dData, 1), UBound(dData, 2))
    
    drg.Value = dData
    
End Sub
```

- This one is the same but uses variables for the array limits.

```vb
Sub ArrayTest2()

    Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws = ActiveSheet ' improve!
    
    Dim srg As Range: Set srg = ws.Range("A1:E3")
    Dim rCount As Long: rCount = srg.Rows.Count
    Dim cCount As Long: cCount = srg.Columns.Count
    
    Dim sData(): sData = srg.Value
    
    Dim dData(): ReDim dData(1 To rCount, 1 To cCount)
    
    Dim r As Long, c As Long
    
    For r = 1 To rCount
        For c = 1 To cCount - 1
            dData(r, c) = sData(r, c + 1)
        Next c
        dData(r, c) = sData(r, 1)
    Next r
    
    Dim dfCell As Range: Set dfCell = ws.Range("A10")
    Dim drg As Range: Set drg = dfCell.Resize(rCount, cCount)
    
    drg.Value = dData
    
End Sub
```

Comment: Certainly helpful in addition to @TimWilliams ' answer; see my late post using MS 365, too.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to the valid posts of *Tim* and *VBasic2008*:

If you dispose of *version* **MS 365** and its [`Sequence()` function](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/sequence-function-57467a98-57e0-4817-9f14-2eb78519ca90) you can redefine the existing *column order* from e.g.

```
Array(1,2,3,4,5) ~~> to Array(5,1,2,3,4)
```

and try the following example code (in connection with the restructuring features of the `Index()` function):

```
Option Explicit                           ' head of code module

Sub ShiftArray()
'[1]get datafield
    Dim data: data = Sheet1.Range("A1:E3")
'[2]reorder columns via sequence Array(2, 3, 4, 5, 1)
    data = Application.Index(data, rowOrder(data), colOrder(data))
'[3]write to any target
    Sheet1.Range("A11").Resize(UBound(data), UBound(data, 2)) = data
End Sub
```

**Helper functions**

```
Function rowOrder(datafield)
'Purp: get all existing row numbers as vertical 2-dim 1-based array
    rowOrder = Evaluate("=Sequence(" & UBound(datafield, 1) & ",1,1,1)")
End Function
```

```
Function colOrder(datafield, Optional IsLeftShift As Boolean = True)
'Purp: get column numbers as "flat" 1-dim 1-based array
    Dim colcount As Long: colcount = UBound(datafield, 2)
    Dim tmp
    If IsLeftShift Then
        tmp = Evaluate("=Sequence(1," & colcount & ",2,1)")
        tmp(colcount) = 1           ' redefine last element, e.g. {2,3,4,5,1}
    Else
        tmp = Evaluate("=Sequence(1," & colcount & ",0,1)")
        tmp(1) = colcount           ' redefine 1st element,  e.g. {5,1,2,3,4}
    End If
    colOrder = tmp
End Function
```

**Note**

*If you prefer a tabular Excel approach via MS 365, you might procede even more directly via*

```
=HSTACK(B1:E3;A1:A3)
```

or

```
=HSTACK(DROP(A1:E3;;1);DROP(A1:E3;0;-4))
```

*as formula in your spilling target cell, optionally made more readable by defining `LET` variables :-)*

Even better thanks to VBasic2008 's comment via `TAKE()`:

```
=LET(Data,A1:E3,HSTACK(DROP(Data,,1),TAKE(Data,,1)))
```

*Hint: If you* **don't** *dispose of MS 365, you can build the column order array also via loop.*

**Related post**

- [Some pecularities of the `Application.Index()` function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51688593/excel-vba-insert-new-first-column-in-datafield-array-without-loops-or-api-call/51714153#51714153)

Comment: Creative as always. Are you aware that you can use `WorksheetFunction` or `Application` with `Sequence` e.g.: `... = Application.Sequence(UBound(datafield, 1), 1, 1, 1)`? Also, in this case, instead 
 of the ugly `DROP(A1:E3,0,-4)` you could use the nice `TAKE(A1:E3,,1)`. I prefer something like `=LET(Data,A1:E3,HSTACK(DROP(Data,,1),TAKE(Data,,1)))`.

Comment: Thank you for the additional information, which will certainly be valuable additions for many users. @VBasic2008