# Excel VBA - ordering columns into range

Tags: excel, vba, range, union

I have a multi-sheet workbook I'm looping through to pull out key data ranges into an array. A couple of the sheets don't follow the standard format and so instead of simply grabbing Range("D6:G100"), I need to piece it together from other columns, and re-order them (just in code, not modifying the sheet).

Tried

`Set rTaskRange = Union(Range("D6:D100"), Range("H6:H100"), Range("I6:I100"), Range("G6:G100"))`

But in the immediate window, I can see VBA is reverting the column order back to original. And also lying to me because columns E and F seem to be included even though it says they're not.

```
?rTaskRange.address
$D$6:$D$100,$G$6:$I$100
```

So the question is: how to build a range out of 4 non-contiguous columns, and also re-arrange them so that (in this example) I is the 3rd column in the range?

Comment: Seems like an XY problem. If you're pulling non-contiguous ranges into an array, [you'll need to loop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18993915/get-values-from-union-of-non-contiguous-ranges-into-array-with-vba-with-a-simple). So just loop in the order you want.

Comment: "I have a multi-sheet workbook ..." - the code you are showing doesn't explicitly say what sheet the `Range()`s should be on. You need to add that qualifier, otherwise it's going to use the `Range()` on whatever the ActiveSheet is.  ...e.g. `...Union(Worksheets("Sheet10").Range("D6:D100")...`

Comment: all seem to be correct - it unites the range G:I and separately shows D -see the link https://vremya-ne-zhdet.ru/vba-excel/metod-application-union/?ysclid=lmkpj5pdfp963082746  so rhe result is the array of ranges 'cos the ranges don't touch

Comment: "columns E and F seem to be included even though it says they're not" - what makes you think that though?

Comment: ...note that because `rTaskRange` is a discontinuous/multi-area range, you can't loop over it using something like `For i=1 to rTaskRange.Columns.Count: Debug.Print rTaskRange.Columns(i).Address: Next i` - that will start with the first area but then just continue from there, ignoring the other areas in the range.  I'm guessing that's why you think columns E and F are included?

Comment: C.f. [Array values not appearing ...](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75735674/array-values-not-appearing-when-posted-in-excel-sheet)